# Making people with close permissions aware of certain questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, vote-to-close

While some questions that need closing are easy to spot, others are less so. For example, a perfectly valid question that belongs on another site. It won't get much activity since no one can answer it.

Right now one solution seems to be to add a `belongs-on-x` tag, but should that really be the way to do it?

Posts can be flagged. Would it be possible to use this feature for more than reporting offensive behavior?

Comment: Flagging isn't just for "offensive" etc. One of the flag reasons is "Requires Moderator attention".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get 10k+ rep you get access to moderator tools that provide, among other things, a list of questions that have the most number of close votes. I often go through the list and see what the questions are and why people think they need to be closed, and if I agree I cast my own vote.

While I agree that users that can close (3k+) but don't have access to the moderator tools (10k+) have a harder time finding questions that are appropriate to close, I think that there are enough 10k+ mods to take care of the obvious ones. And if a [3k, 10k) user does find a question that they think needs to be moved, they can always flag it for moderator intervention or, as you said, tag it as "belongs-on-X".

In other words, I think that the system has multiple ways for people with various reputations to identify and close/move appropriate questions, that I don't think another mechanism is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we encourage flagging for anything at all out of the ordinary. Please use it!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/