# Would like to be able to ignore all closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a closed question be given special tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/can-a-closed-question-be-given-special-tags)

I ignore certain tags, but I don't know of a way to make the closed-questions invisible.  Is this possible?  If not, could it be?

One solution would be to add a "closed" tag to questions that are closed, and removing it if they are re-opened.

Comment: add "closed:0" to all your searches

Answer (score 3):

I don't like this idea. It's important for everyone to help keep SOFU sites clean, by closing questions that don't belong, and re-opening questions that do belong and were (in your view) incorrectly closed).

In my view, this option would essentially encourage users to opt out of doing their bit towards keeping the sites clean.

Finally, if this were to be done, please don't do it by overloading the meaning of tags.

Comment: I wish we had those super mega upvotes right about now.

Comment: Perhaps those of us that are unable to vote to reopen should be allowed to filter out the closed ones?

Comment: @FarmBoy - maybe that'd make sense (though it'd go against the grain to take functionality *away* as you gain reputation), but there are still things you can do do closed questions - downvote/retag/edit; so I'd still not be in favour.