# Classic Re-Tag Discussion on some good ole ASP (Classic)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Not sure if [this re-tag request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/3064#3064) needs to get resurrected from the original "Great Tagging Reog" discussion, but as someone who still eats, sleeps, and breathes Classic ASP (well, Classic ASP pays for the food and the roof) its bothered me that there's an `asp` and `asp-classic` tag.

While I can understand that some of the questions (~20% based on sloppy math and random sampling) are from people too lazy to finish ASP with a .NET, it would probably help to sort those out from the Classic questions.

Is there a way to selectively re-tag? i.e. if it has other tags like `vbscript` change it to `asp-classic` and if it has other tags like `c#` change it to `asp.net` and then see how many are left.

I have insomnia, and may just undertake some manual work, but 531 questions is likely to cure my sleep issues before I finish...

Thoughts?

**Edit**

Just bringing this back up as the `asp` tag is fairly useless since it doesn't differentiate between classic and .net. Or is this something that's going to have to wait until there's a blacklist for tags?

Comment: You'll see many robots in that time if you're going with manual retag.

Comment: "Robots are everywhere, and they eat old people's medicine for fuel."

Comment: I can't sleep, and I've run into a slump on my current projects so I figured some "simpler" work would be in order. :)

Comment: I will admit that some of these questions seem to be more ambiguous than I thought was possible...

Comment: The economy hurting the CAPTCHA business too? I just got "unemployment sackman"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only see questions tagged with one on explicit appearance of another, slam them together.

For those tagged [**[asp]** and **[vbscript]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp+vbscript) you only have 59.

For those [**[asp]** and **[c#]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp+c%23), you're down to only 37.

And now that list of 531 doesn't look so menacing.

Comment: knocked out the ~60 [asp] [vbscript]

Comment: How many CAPTCHA forms did you see?

Comment: Not that many as I was taking my time. I read the posts to make sure I didn't mis-tag, and I was watching TV so my attention tended to wander... especially on some of the more convoluted, poorly worded questions. Made me wish I had the rep to help 'em out.

Answer (score 1):

The `[asp]` tag should be dumped. The question is: how?

Certainly, once all questions are moved out of there it should be [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list), because it's completely ambiguous.

I was working on this just now, and it seems that *most* of the questions tagged `[asp]` deal with Classic ASP topics.

Now, since this question was originally posted, the `[asp]` tag has ballooned quite a bit to 859 questions. I cut that down to 773 by eliminating the combination of `[asp]` + `[.net]`, mostly into `[asp.net]` (some of the questions actually dealt with Classic ASP topics).

After that, I did a search for [`[asp]` `-[asp.net]` `-[c#]` `-[asp.net-mvc]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp%20-asp.net%20-c%23%20-asp.net-mvc%20-vb.net), which resulted in 600 questions. That means by eliminating the ~173 questions (roughly 2x what I just did) that don't deal with Classic ASP, and then manually going through the remaining 600 questions to filter *out* anything not Classic ASP, then a mass rename can proceed. I hope my assumption (3rd paragraph) actually holds true!

Comment: Can't agree. I prefer `[asp]` and absolutely dislike `[asp-classic]`. Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx has zero references to term *Classic*. Also http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+-%22asp.net%22+site%3Amicrosoft.com and http://www.google.com/search?q=classic+asp+site%3Amicrosoft.com . See the numbers of results

Comment: @aba: I don't think you're understanding what's going on here. Please read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/whats-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-ambiguous-tags).

Answer (score 0):

After you go and do that you are still left with **240** questions with the [**[​asp]**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp) tag.

Try this search to see for yourself   [**[​asp]**   -**[c#]**   -**[vbscript]**   -**[asp-classic]**   -**[*.net*]**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp+-c%23+-vbscript+-asp-classic+-%7E.net%7E)

So while it would definitely help to reduce the clutter, it only reduces it to about half of it's original size.

---

I find it interesting that the *next* highest correlated tag to [**[​asp]**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp+-c%23+-vbscript+-asp-classic+-%7E.net%7E), is [**[​php]**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php) <sup><sub>(After the proposed retagging effort)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Hi all, I realise classic asp is old news to most people, but still used by some :)

There appears to be 685 questions tagged 'asp' and 875 questions tagged 'asp-classic', could these be merged to asp-classic? I recognise that some tagged asp may actually be referring to asp.net and need to be merged with that tag.

Will this kind of clean-up need to be done every six months, or is there a feature on the way to prevent this kind of issue?

Cheers all...

Comment: I hope not... especially since it was never finished the first time. A fair number of the questions tagged `asp` were in fact `asp.net` (and in some cases, tagged with both) - and that's just the start of the fun.

Comment: Is there a way to blacklist a tag such as 'asp' because it is too vague and open to being mis-interpreted? I can only imagine this problem is going to grow bigger as the site grows bigger.

Comment: See the related discussions at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list