# Ambiguous tag: mdb

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice that the tag mdb has become a problem as it refers to both JBoss Message Driven Bean (as far as I can tell) and MS-Access. I am tempted to remove all mdb tags and replace them with, say, JBoss-MDB and MS-Access. I should be glad of an opinion on this as there are 57 in this tag at the moment.

Comment: Either way, it's not going to be easy. Manually retagging is always unpleasant.

Comment: @Remou I've raised the further issue of retagging MS-Access to MS-Jet-ACE here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO IT BABY!!  correctly-tagged-things-are-good.

Answer (score 1):

Go for it. Just take your time and make sure that the question is really related to the tag you think its related to. A while back my insomnia cranked up to 11 [so I did some similar work to pass the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/classic-re-tag-discussion-on-some-good-ole-asp-classic). You'd be surprised how many posts won't have anything to do with either technology - or both. Also be prepared to be surprised at just how vague a question can be.

If you're taking your time and checking the questions you also won't run into that many CAPTCHAs. Always a plus. :)