# Tag Discussion: [which-language] on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, specific-question

While perusing the [ambiguous <kbd>language</kbd> tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/) (1/3 of the way through right now!), I checked out what tags we currently have with either "language", "lang", or "lingu" in them. One of the ones that caught my eye was [<kbd>which-language</kbd> (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/which-language). They're all questions about "Which programming language should I use for this project?" Do we think it is better to keep this kind of tag, or should it be reassigned to, say, <kbd>programming-languages</kbd>? All 27 currently tagged are about programming languages specifically.

We already have question-descriptive tags that apply to the nature of the question itself rather than the problem raised in the question. Probably the most well-known one is the <kbd>subjective</kbd> tag. There is merit to keeping these kind of tags if they are a prevalent class of questions; it would be useful for specific classes of question that could probably benefit from being grouped together. However, the decision of whether a question class is prevalent enough is bigger than one person can make. Care needs to be exercised to prevent a growing snowball of tags resulting things in like <kbd>what-is-this</kbd> and <kbd>how-do-i</kbd>, which in turn means tags will lean away from actually describing the problem itself.

**EDIT**

While we're at it, the related [<kbd>language-choice</kbd> (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-choice) is 40% questions that would be <kbd>which-language</kbd>, and in review of the other 60%, I'm also concerned about its status as a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through some of the questions tagged `[which-language]`, I'm not a big fan.  There are a few decent questions that might be of general interest (e.g., [What programming language will enable me to enter a very long number without converting it to floating point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653131/what-programming-language-will-enable-me-to-enter-a-very-long-number-without-conv)), but many of these questions amount to "What language should I learn next?"  I think a lot of the questions should be closed and the tag merged into `[programming-languages]`.

As for question-descriptive tags, like `[subjective]`, I've never really thought they had much use except something to add to my Ignore list.  I know it's impossible to get rid of now, but I'd really like to see the use of that tag and many like it reduced.

Comment: I, too, dislike [subjective] (it's a dependent-adjective that refers to only the question, so double negatives!), but it is way too large and prevalent to consider removing. As I go through the [language], should I flag the questions which would classify as [which-language]?

Comment: Yes, you can flag those and I'll take a look at them.

Comment: I agree with you but have used up my upvotes for the day. (And it's only 10am!)

Answer (score 0):

> should it be reassigned to, say, [programming-languages]?

I'd say yes, especially as [[programming-languages]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) is already in use for such questions.

Comment: "Yes" isn't an answer to an "Option A or Option B?" question!

Comment: Sorry, still having my mind half on my work ;)

Comment: @ccornet: Yes it is. It means at least one of the options is true.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bill, the `[which-language]` tag is not very useful. I think such questions should probably be tagged with some combo like `[programming-languages] [discussion]` or `[programming-languages] [suggestion]`

Comment: `[discussion]` and `[suggestion]` are meta-tags.  They're fine (even necessary) for this site, but I wouldn't want to use them on any of the main trilogy sites.

Comment: I agree that they belong on meta, but `[discussion]` is used 500+ times on SO...

Comment: @Bill: I guess the problem is, "which language to use" is probably going to be subjective, it's asking for suggestions and will cause a discussion...

Comment: You're right.  I hadn't noticed that tag was already so prevalent.  :(