# Tags for "odd" things

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

We have an [[odd]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odd) problem on Stack Overflow. There are only <s>7</s> 6 questions currently with this tag, but it covers 3 possible meanings and one of them I believe is undesirable. The last one is one I'm not sure how to take care of, hence bringing this up for discussion. The first two are merely around to establish the ambiguity of a plain "odd" tag.

**1. Oddness**

Only one question used the tag in this fashion, and I have already removed it. Considering the rally of support behind removing tags like [[weird]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/remove-weird-tag) and [strange], it made sense to get rid of it just like I plan to tackle the rest of its brethren like [odd-behaviour].

**2. Quantities/Values Not Divisible By Two**

[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276909/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780763/) use odd to refer to odd numbers. We could probably solve this with [odd-numbers] or [odd-number]. Very simple and meshes well with the existing numeric tags.

**3. Alternating Elements of an Iteration**

The meat of this question is the questions that use [odd] for this. Basically, when people want "every other element" of something. Sometimes it specifically is the odd-numbered iterations, but not all of them. Considering the lack of an "even" tag, I imagine those are tagged "odd" just because it was around.

I can't think of a proper tag for this concept, though. What are your thoughts?

Comment: There's also `[scanner]`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scanner) which I've seen used for both the optical kind (barcode scanner etc) and `String` scanning (`java.util.Scanner`).

Comment: Related (should help you): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/whats-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-ambiguous-tags

Comment: @polygene I would actually recommend opening a separate question about that ambiguous tag. I'd like to keep this post's focus on `[odd]`

Comment: Very late comment, I know, but I just checked and `[scanner]` is no longer used on SO.

Comment: Two questions for meaning 2? That's very ... odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Getting every odd variable in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780763/)* <s>[number] [odd]</s>
Wanted to tag [beginner], but that's a meta-tag, and I'm trying to use less of those. The list manipulation just didn't seem significant enough for [list], [list-manipulation], or similar.

*[addClass every nth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260277/)* <s>[odd] [alt]</s> [alternate-elements]
The tag [alternate] could be a verb or a noun and ambiguous that way and [alternates] seems more "alternatives", otherwise I would've used it instead of [alternate-elements].  The tag [alt] only has 14 other uses, but every one of them refers to the alt attribute of <img> or the alt key on keyboards.

*[How to test if an array contains a pair of numbers whose product is odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276909/)* <s>[odd] [learning]</s> [beginner]
While [beginner] is a meta-tag like [learning], that question has already gone through discussion on it, and [beginner] at least has an aspect of tagging the question rather than the OP's motivation.

*[How to remove every other line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560411/)* <s>[odd] [line]</s> [alternate-elements]

*[How to fill one UItableViewCell with odd and even entries from an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796878/)* <s>[odd]</s> [alternate-elements]

*[Optimize code performance when odd/even threads are doing different things in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856758/)* <s>[odd]</s>