# Blacklist the [idea] tag as ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags, tag-block-request

SO has currently [<strike>451</strike> 444(??) posts tagged with `intellij-idea`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) and [<strike>15</strike> 0 posts tagged with `idea`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea). The latter list used to be longer until 2 days ago, when I browsed through it, noticed that the majority of the posts were about IntelliJ IDEA anyway, and retagged the rest (AFAIR 7 posts, including for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258740/any-ideas-on-what-to-do-by-cloud-computing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158080/how-does-one-create-an-enthusiastic-development-team) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514466/a-project-idea-which-fits-with-sun-certified-java-programmer-scjp-preparation)) to [`ideas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ideas) or [`project-ideas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-ideas).

I also suggested `idea` as a synonym for `intellij-idea`, but today I became a bit hesitant about this.

Obviously "idea" has a much more general meaning than IntelliJ's product. So I am afraid automatically converting `idea` to `intellij-idea` in the future may be wrong in some cases. Can we expect that users will notice and use `ideas` when they mean to, instead of ending up incorrectly associated with `intellij-idea`? Based on its actual usage, the current consensus seems to be leaning towards `idea` meaning `intellij-idea`, but still it is sort of kidnapping a word... What does the community think?

---

#### Update

As I just realized, [there are precedents to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags). And the logical consensus seems to be to separate such terms into two (or more) distinct, unambiguous tags. Which in this case are already present:

- `intellij-idea`
- `ideas`
- `project-ideas`
- [`business-ideas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-ideas)

I have already done <strike>part of</strike> the renaming<strike>, and I can do the rest</strike>. Then, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/whats-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-ambiguous-tags/50223#50223) mentions the possibility of blacklisting tags - to me this would be the best final solution in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make ambiguous synonyms. You should only propose a synonym where it is going to be indisputable that the person meant the parent tag. Not everyone with ideas has intellij-ideas, exactly as you say. See [Synonyms mean interchangeable, not similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar).

And when it comes to plurals, you can never expect that users will always be able to pick up on the right choice. That's why we get the singular/plural problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]