# Please burninate [software] and similar tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, tag-block-request

Water is wet, Stack Overflow is about software development, and these tags carry no information:

- [application-development](/questions/tagged/application-development), [general-development](/questions/tagged/general-development)
- [develop](/questions/tagged/develop), [developer](/questions/tagged/developer), [developers](/questions/tagged/developers)
- [program](/questions/tagged/program), [programs](/questions/tagged/programs), [programmatic](/questions/tagged/programmatic), [programatically](/questions/tagged/programatically) (*sic*), [programmer](/questions/tagged/programmer), [programmers](/questions/tagged/programmers)
- [practical-programming](/questions/tagged/practical-programming), [programming-skills](/questions/tagged/programming-skills)
- [software](/questions/tagged/software), [software-companies](/questions/tagged/software-companies), [software-development](/questions/tagged/software-development), [software-process](/questions/tagged/software-process)
- [solo-developer](/questions/tagged/solo-developer), [team-development](/questions/tagged/team-development)

And these tags are a strong indication of a question that doesn't belong here:

- [developer-machine](/questions/tagged/developer-machine) (use [Hardware] instead)
- [developer-skills](/questions/tagged/developer-skills)
- [future-development](/questions/tagged/future-development)
- [home-development](/questions/tagged/home-development), [personal-software-process](/questions/tagged/personal-software-process), [professional-development](/questions/tagged/professional-development)

And while I'm at it, a few synonym requests:

- [sqldeveloper](/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) → [sql-developer](/questions/tagged/sql-developer)
- [website-development](/questions/tagged/website-development) → [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development)

Comment: `programmatically` is a tag used to give the impression an 'off-topic' question is really relevant to SO.

Comment: You forgot christmas, missing, schools.  Etcetera, try to limit the hit list to tags that are routinely ab-used or the dragon will run out of gas.

Comment: Is the title supposed to be a reference to Trogdor?

Comment: @Keoki yeah when a tag gets destroyed by Jeff and company, Jeff tends to post a "This tag has been BURNINTAED" picture with Trogdor in it, like so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59595/so-blacklist-the-idea-tag-as-ambiguous/87430#87430

Comment: I agree, we have done a similar thing at Super User: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2017/can-the-hardware-and-software-tags-be-obliterated

Comment: @pavium: I disagree. Do you think [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689904/gracefully-exit-explorer-programmatically) was not relevant to SO?

Comment: Sorry, @Mehrdad, at that point in the middle of the night, I tend to generalise.

Comment: I did your synonyms as well, but I am unclear what you want done with the items in the middle.

Comment: @Jeff The first group of tags are saying “this is about programming”, which is useless. The second group of tags are saying “this isn't about programming” or “this isn't a good question”, so this is an invitation for the community to look for questions to close or retag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed, thanks for the suggestions, the following were burninated:

- [application-development](/questions/tagged/application-development), [general-development](/questions/tagged/general-development)
- [develop](/questions/tagged/develop), [developer](/questions/tagged/developer), [developers](/questions/tagged/developers)
- [program](/questions/tagged/program), [programs](/questions/tagged/programs), [programmatic](/questions/tagged/programmatic), [programmer](/questions/tagged/programmer), [programmers](/questions/tagged/programmers)
- [practical-programming](/questions/tagged/practical-programming), [programming-skills](/questions/tagged/programming-skills)
- [software](/questions/tagged/software), [software-companies](/questions/tagged/software-companies), [software-development](/questions/tagged/software-development), [software-process](/questions/tagged/software-process)
- [team-development](/questions/tagged/team-development)

[image: tag burninated]

I left [solo-developer](/questions/tagged/solo-developer) and [programatically](/questions/tagged/programatically) for now.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions are `development` specific or `process` specific, as opposed to technical programming questions.  Some of those tags need to stay though they could certainly be consolidated.

[programmatically](/questions/tagged/programmatically) while usually taken care of in the text of the question is probably good to have so people won't make the wrong assumption about questions that could be taken the wrong way (as has actually happened).