# Burninate the [apps] and [application] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [apps](/questions/tagged/apps) tag is used over 700 times on Stack Overflow, and has the following description:

> Shortened from applications, commonly pointing applications in the online stores for mobile devices.

The [application](/questions/tagged/application) tag has over 10,000 uses, with the following description:

> An application is a software program designed to help the user to perform singular or multiple related specific tasks.

These both seem roughly equivalent to having a tag for [programs](/questions/tagged/programs) or [software](/questions/tagged/software) (which was [burninated previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96470/1288)).  Can we edit | close | delete questions with the [apps](/questions/tagged/apps) or [application](/questions/tagged/application) tags?

Comment: Just as a note in Android is a class called Application how should that questions been tagged?

Comment: @rekire Excellent point. We'll probably want to keep the tag for those few questions that are about that class.

Comment: Are you trying to go through these first? A cursory examination doesn't turn up much that would be lost by just burning them...

Comment: @Shog9 I wouldn't mind if the ones tagged [android + application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+application) were left to pick through, but we can probably just burn the rest.

Comment: @rekire I ended up creating the [android-application] tag for questions dealing specifically with the `Application` class.

Comment: Nope, the application [tag] is back again -- it's been like whack-a-mole; I'll get the tag cleaned up, and the next morning, it's back again.  Been happening all week long.

Comment: @LBT Yes, it looks like [application] is just too popular to die. It needs to go 24 hours without being used before new users can't create it again.  I'll keep it on my watch list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filtered the list down to [android + application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+application), and then further restricted my search to just those questions which contained either `Application` or `.Application` *in a code block.*

This resulted in all of 85 questions. You're free to retag these if you wish; I think it's pretty clear that finding them among the thousands of other questions with those tags would've been pretty difficult though, so I went ahead and burned these tags.

[Please care for the widows and orphans...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

#### Questions possibly about android.app.Application

- [Indirectly extend Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536749)
- [Contacts App crashes when switching between Dialer to Call log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1922292)
- [Android Application data should not be released by android OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2085799)
- [Binding a Service to an android.app.Activity vs Binding it to an android.app.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3154899)
- [Can I create custom global methods in my Android Application class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503892)
- [Access Application class from class other then Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3666368)
- [Global Variables to specify a starting Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4236491)
- [Determine list of permissions used by an installed application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4461504)
- [AIDL - What's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4881954)
- [Does Application instance exist after starting any component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5233454)
- [Global application class with stack of activities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5280219)
- [Android: How to run service when application is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5560090)
- [Trying to access resources from an Application Context in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5637096)
- [Android JUnit: Define a different Application subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827139)
- [How to trigger a Dialog from an Application instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6038636)
- [Extending Application class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6082119)
- [My application launchs twice on Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6136464)
- [Android launch applications detail page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6238946)
- [Retrieving application information from package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6418945)
- [Android Application force closes. (NullPointerException / ToggleButton)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6462243)
- [Lost global variables in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6607356)
- [Application class can be used for store data? (persistent data)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822602)
- [How to get installed application name in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6838223)
- [How to run code on Application opens in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6923285)
- [Need an explanation about Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6931621)
- [Two onCreate() methods in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7079676)
- [Can I startService from Application#onCreate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7198863)
- [Why wouldn't my image display (from gallery) when in portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7263902)
- [R.java not getting generated properly for Android Library Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7384238)
- [Android ArrayList in Application Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7430637)
- [When does Application's onCreate() method get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7686482)
- [How to access an already-running Application Context from a Sync Adapter service in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8018266)
- [Alphabatize list of installed apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8174360)
- [Android controlling views from Application Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8626335)
- [How to make my app become system app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8753191)
- [How to filter system applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8834887)
- [Android application AndroidRuntime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9014363)
- [Application subclass gets deleted on "Android Tools"->Export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9112853)
- [Application context returning null when using getFilesDir()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9216926)
- [Android App is crashing when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9390361)
- [BroadcastReceiver on Application.onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9550440)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9630399
- [Changing static variable in application thread has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9876347)
- [getting Icons of applications running on device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9936996)
- [Global variable extend application class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10059733)
- [Is it safe to save the app context to a static variable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10258507)
- [Extend Application in Android Why does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10259006)
- [How can I get the icons of the applications in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434473)
- [Application Object Won't Share](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440217)
- [Application Class with Database Trouble in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10526513)
- [FATAL EXCEPTION: main error - Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10694310)
- [How to filter some of the application apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10787403)
- [Android State Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10933930)
- [cannot find symbol on getApplication() on AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11167774)
- [Android: applicationInfo.loadDescription() always returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11172107)
- [android application size, return 0 when ask for codeSize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304612)
- [List out installed/running applications in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11391451)
- [Add our own application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11559895)
- [Saving data in application class error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11579320)
- [FATAL EXCEPTION: main( Sorry the application radio has stopped unexpectly)OnButtonClick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11687025)
- [Multiple Application Files in one Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12137892)
- [Android "ClassNotFoundException" occurs sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12557585)
- [Show toast at current Activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12730675)
- [How to load all user installed apps into gridview and make them clickable in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12754556)
- [Android Application class method onCreate being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12809737)
- [Extending Android Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12834379)
- [When I develop an Android application ,how to exit this application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12930102)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/12963086
- [Use android Application class run a thread background to post some data to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13209639)
- [Application subclass and singleton. When new instance is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13500414)
- [extends Application example causing program to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13537323)
- [Inner class within application class, is it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13564057)
- [What are the Drawbacks of declaring objects in Application subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13991992)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/14293259
- [How to programmatically get launch time of other apps in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14502668)
- [All Apps activity failes to load android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14542771)
- [How to allow accessing the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14932604)
- [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application - casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15001204)
- [How to launch system apps programmatically or how to filter out launchable system apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15378495)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/16556506
- [How to get the package name of an application and then launch that app using Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16683455)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981412
- [How to get android play store installed apps packages through android code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17042902)
- [How to use google analytics module in titanium android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17274590)
- [Android - Combine Two Application Into One Application Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17460295)

Comment: `if question.tags() == 'untagged' and question.lock() != 'historical' and question.score() <= 0: question.delete()`, or something.

Comment: Yeah, retagging these does seem a little bit easier than picking through 2500 questions.  Thanks!  :)