# Please remove the asm -> assembly synonym

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

ASM is a tool for manipulating Java byte code, while `assembly` refers to assembly language.

Some people write asm for assembly language, but that can easily be fixed by retagging.

Comment: `[java-asm]` perhaps?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What's this about labelled tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags).

Comment: +1 as this is a real problem, even if I don't like the solution put forwared in the quesion.

Comment: I'd prefer `[java-bytecode-asm]` over `[java-asm]`.

Answer (score 7):

"ASM" as a shorthand for "Assembly" predates Java by decades and is a much more common use. In fact if you [google for it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=asm) the first programming related results refers to assembly.

Comment: That doesn't mean that anything that is tagged "asm" should forcibly be retagged "assembly". The current implementation may be appropriate for hyphen/no-hyphen variants, but not for three letter acronyms with multiple meanings.

Comment: i agree, *asm* is universally recognised as standing for *assembly* or *assembly language*. If the Java crowd want to hijack that moniker then they need to tolerate the confusion they have caused.

Comment: I just tried your Google link and for me it shows result 3 "asm.ow2.org/" (Java), result 5 en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language

Comment: @Martin: My google shows the exact opposite: [Wikipedia's Assembly Language article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) at #3, [asm.ow2.org](http://asm.ow2.org/) at #5...

Answer (score 6):

While I can't support de-aliasing `[asm]` so it can be made to refer to something else, **I do think this synonym should be broken**. `[assembly]` has become ambiguous mostly because of this synonym, between topics about .NET assemblies and assembly language (and at least the Java topic as well).

Standard protocol for ambiguous tags applies:

- Create `[asm-framework]` for the Java-related topic and retag to this as appropriate
- Retag assembly-language-related to `[assembly-language]`
- Retag .NET-related to `[.net-assembly]` (probably after the previous 2 steps, this can be done en masse, because by that point anything else not related deserves to be swept along)
- Blacklist both `[asm]` and `[assembly]`

Comment: Can I get an explanation on the downvote, please? If we're going to fix this, we need all sides of the discussion out in the open.

Comment: I think you are going overboard with your proposal to retag everything and blacklist tags.  Currently everything is neatly sorted into `asm`, `assembly` and `assemblies`, I have been retagging them for a long while. As for specific problems, `asm-framework` would not be recognized as relating to the ASM which manipulates Java bytecodes. Then there are also Maven assemblies, which conceptually seem to be the same thing as .net assemblies, deployable software components. Sorry for not explaining the downvote earlier.

Comment: @starblue: They appear to be sorted, but as I've pointed out, `[assembly]` contains questions on 2 distinct topics, which makes the tag ambiguous. Since the goal is for users to be able to search topics by tag, it's necessary to disambiguate tags using the process I've outlined [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/whats-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-ambiguous-tags/50223#50223).