# What to do about conflicting tag names?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle tags with multiple meanings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings)

On Stack Overflow, I keep finding posts tagged [raven](/questions/tagged/raven) that should be tagged [ravendb](/questions/tagged/ravendb).  They are two very different products by different authors for different purposes.

Should I just retag these manually when they come up?  Or is there a way for the system to suggest the [ravendb](/questions/tagged/ravendb) tag based on the question content?

There aren't that many, so it's not that big of a deal if the answer is to handle it manually.  I'm just not sure about the guidelines around this.

Perhaps the [raven](/questions/tagged/raven) tag should be disallowed and replaced with something more suitable for that project, such as [raven-sentry](/questions/tagged/raven-sentry) or [raven-python](/questions/tagged/raven-python)?

I've already retaged the questions that were mistagged.  I'd just like to avoid future cases of this.

**Update**

I found these related questions:
 - [How should ambiguous tags be dealt with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/how-should-ambiguous-tags-be-dealt-with)
 - [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)

So how to request a blacklist for the [raven] tag?

Comment: This is an ambiguity problem, not a synonym problem.  `raven` != `ravendb`.

Comment: @Charles - yes, exactly.  Also, was thinking [sentry-raven] may also be a synonym for that product since raven is an add-on for sentry.  But I'd like it if [raven] would then be not allowed so the user has to choose the appropriate tag.

Comment: @AustinHenley He is saying that there are questions incorrectly tagged raven when they should be tagged ravendb because they are two different product.s This is the opposite of synonyms.