# Let's Ban the [ASP] Tag on StackOverflow!

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

- If the question is about ASP.NET, then it should say [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)
- If the question is  about Classic ASP, then it should say [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic)

I can think of no valid reason to tag a question with [asp](/questions/tagged/asp). Let's get rid of it entirely.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/classic-re-tag-discussion-on-some-good-ole-asp-classic ?

Comment: Asps. Very dangerous. You go first...

Comment: @Jon: no, it's not a dupe of that one. I'm saying that "asp" should simply not be used at all, as its use is almost always a mistake.

Comment: oh and at the same time, most of the questions tagged as ASP.NET should be re-tagged as ASP.NET-webforms or similar (because only few questions are really about the ASP.NET framework).

Comment: @M4N: At the moment, I'd say most [ASP.NET] questions which don't have another tag like [ASP.NET-MVC] really are ASP.NET Web Forms questions. This might change in a couple of years.

Comment: shouldn't actually be classic-asp? the wrong way round seems wierd to me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**It's a trap!**

The problem is that `asp` is a trap tag for ASP.Net.  We'll *never* be able to stop clueless users from tagging asp.net questions `asp`.  It sucks for those still using the original asp, but the *only* way we can have a clear, unambiguous tag devoted to that technology is to give it an unambiguous name.  Thus, `asp-classic` exists.

However, we now have a mess on our hands in the `asp` tag: over 3000 questions, about half of which are for asp.net and half for classic asp. That's way too many, too closely spread, to deal with automatically.

I agree, then, that the best possible result here is to restrict using the `asp` tag in *new* questions. This will force users to make an unambiguous tag choice. This will at least prevent the problem from getting worse.

At this point we need to work the existing questions, and there is a choice about how to do that: we could work to remove the tag entirely, or we could work to merely clean up the ASP.Net questions, and when that is done restore the `asp` tag as a synonym of asp-classic.  Of those, I think the latter is ideal option, but it will be hard to implement as it will get increasingly hard to know which questions have been worked. Thus I propose we do both: clean up *all* the questions in the `asp` tag, but when done set it up as a synonym for `asp-classic`.

**Update**
This has now happened. I spent a good bit of time on this over the holidays and cleaned up every single question with the old `asp` tag by hand — all 3000+. It went much faster than you might think. At this time, the tag no longer exists, and [a mod was kind enough to create an synonym to `asp-classic`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119087/135887). Hopefully users intending it to mean asp.net will now spot the (much more obvious) error and correct their questions.

Answer (score 21):

#### I disagree.

Before ASP.NET was here, the framework was called 'ASP', not 'ASP classic'. Will we have to rename each language/technology to "classic" "classicer" "classicest" each time a new version appears?

Comment: The problem here is that too many people use [ASP] when they really mean [ASP.NET], making the tag much less useful. By removing the [ASP] option, they would be forced to choose one.

Comment: @Gabe: indeed. This A represented what I thought, I then took a look at Qs [tagged ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp): Most are ASP.NET (quite a lot are tagged both). There's a few less now :-).

Comment: @Gabe - you are right, but the solution is for attentive users with the required rep level to edit the tags, not eliminate a legitimate tag.

Comment: There's a difference between a new version and a total incompatible rewrite.  Besides that, classic asp is so old at this point that it needs to be specifically called out when that is what's being referred to.

Answer (score 6):

This makes sense, but how would a person looking for ASP classic know to use the [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag?

Comment: What about my suggestion with a new ask prompting for version clarification that automatically cleans up / adds tags.

Comment: wouldn't the auto complete take care of that?  type 'asp' and both 'asp.net' and 'asp-classic' show up.

Comment: @ktrauberman: I don't get auto complete for tags in the search box. Do you?

Comment: I was referring to the tag box when asking/editing a question.  I see your point about the search box.  Does it allow partial terms in the search?

Comment: er.... because ASP Classic is a common term used in IT to differentiate it from ASP.NET?  I know we call it ASP Classic where I work...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that something should be done as the [ASP] tag is almost always used in the wrong way, and as it says DONT use this tag and people still do so remove it is my view.

Answer (score -1):

I agree. The same thing should be done for Visual Basic and all other language-version dependent tags.

Edit: OK, to clarify, I mention VB and C in my comment to John below.

I think a solution would be: if you add a question with tags VB, ASP, C, etc., you should be prompted by a new page; "Please if possible select proper version for your tags" encouraging people to fill in C89 or C99 if they know they want it (everyone should if it's not marked homework).

This will also be good for, say, SQL. You would be prompted about what SQL standard you want *or* what database you are using. Almost all SQL questions I see starts with comments asking for what database (and version) is being used.

Comment: Can you say exactly which tags you're referring to?

Comment: @John vb as mentioned and C springs to mind. It should either be C99 or C89. C-classic could be autocorrected to C89.

Comment: I would agree to [vb], since it probably means either vb.net or vb6 (though maybe VBSCRIPT or VBA), but I'm not so sure about C, which in general could be taken to mean K&R C.

Comment: This is what i love with Meta. Down votes on questions marked "discussion" without any comment. Awesome site this is.

Comment: ASP (classic) and ASP.NET are entirely different languages (like Java and JavaScript). C99 and C89 are nearly identical.

Comment: @Gabe C99 and C89 Nearly identical? Did you vote down my suggestion because of this? Because thats really a clueless comment about those languages.

Comment: C89 and C99 are just different dialects of the same language. The foreword to the C99 standard lists the "major" differences, and it reads like the differences between American English and British English.

Comment: @Gabe I do not agree and i think this is very off topic on the subject. An answer assuming C99 will be invalid for a C89 asker, the code will not compile. C89 sollution for a C99 question is ugly and pure nasty. Please focus on the original topic or make an answer describing why this is a bad idea (probably better).

Comment: I have no problem with the ASP idea. It's the unrelated idea of banning the C tag that I disagree with.

Comment: @Gabe basically i want more tags added. For C i want to see [C] [C89] or [C] [C99] on a question.

Comment: More tags aren't a bad idea, but a quick look at the [C] tag didn't show many questions where a [C89] or [C99] tag would be warranted.

Comment: @Gabe every time i write an answer on a C tag i assume C89. Which is rather stupid 2011.

Comment: How many of your answers in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:586281+[c] would you have answered differently if the question contained a [C89] or [C99] tag?

Comment: @Gabe most of them, they are all answered in C89.

Comment: -1: Two different technologies is not the same as two different variants of the same language. VB5 is closer to VB.NET than ASP is to ASP.NET (OK there are some gross similarities in syntax like there are for C and Java).

Comment: Which ones are you talking about? Of the 7 items on the page, the first one is already C99 (C89 doesn't allow a `for(int i = 0`) and the others are not specific to a version.

Comment: @Gabe that would rather be a typo but yes, C89 "works" in C99. C prety much works in C++, wouldnt call them same language. Maybe we just have different ideas on how languages should be treated. @Richard you dont seem to comment on my suggestion/solution at all but rather on the rant from @Gabe. Typical meta style.

Comment: (Nothing special about ambiguous tags). Yesterday I edited a question about ASP.NET MVC. The user had taged the question with 'mvc' and was only referring to the technology as MVC.