# How do I find questions about ASP Classic?

Tags: support

I've been searching for something about [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages). I use the following search key in Stack Overflow:  `jquery ajax asp`.

However, almost all the questions I find are about [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET). How do I narrow my search to only ASP Classic and not ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search [inside the tag <kbd>asp-classic</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D%20%2bjquery%20%2bajax).

See also this related question: [Let's Ban the [ASP] Tag on StackOverflow!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/lets-ban-the-asp-tag-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Cool new feature: `[tag:snakes]`

Comment: @random: Yes I know, tried that first, but that doesn't work inside a link apparently...

Comment: Either way, that [asp-classic] bungle sure isn't intuitive. How do old people know they're classics?

Comment: My wife at a cocktail party: "I am a radio deejay".  Response: "Ah, I used to have a radio".  That's how they know.

Comment: I still have a radio, and I don't have a TV. I also have a small army of computers. Radio's still better than whatever crap is on TV nowadays. Damned kids these days.

Comment: @Killbog - that's because you're watching Canadian TV.

Comment: @status: While Canadian TV is bad (and worse than American TV), I would never go so far as to say that American TV is *good*. Canadian TV is crap — just like everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Search for your desired topic starting with "classic asp" instead of asp. You can use also
vbscript. Sometimes it helps.