# Where'd the [asp] tag go, and why did it come back?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

I'm having a hard time tracking down where [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) went.  I know there have been a few requests ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/lets-ban-the-asp-tag-on-stackoverflow)) to ban/blacklist/synonym it, but *I can't find which one caused it to stop existing*.

Regardless, at some point, it was no longer a thing.  And now, it is again.  It showed up on the 10k tools new tag list this morning.  I've been retagging questions out of it *all day*, but clueless new users keep trying to use it.

I'm firmly in the "it's ambiguous and you should use [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) or [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) instead" camp.  Unfortunately without knowing what made it disappear, it's hard to recommend the next step.  Our options are:

1. Make it a synonym of [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic), which seems to be how most of the questions that used it today wanted to use it.
2. Make it a synonym of [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)
3. Blacklist it so that users can't possibly pick it and get it wrong.

I'm going to suggest #3, as it has the least horrible outcome at the possible cost of confusing users that don't know that we call pre-.NET ASP "ASP Classic."

Comment: Option 3 seems like the most optimal solution. I think there must now be a generation of developers out there who've no idea what classic ASP is and assume `asp` => `asp.net`. I am intrigued as well as to how all evidence of it has been wiped clean.

Comment: @Kev Is it possible that someone actually manually retagged those questions and the tag just aged away until someone used it again? I'm not sure how many questions were in it to begin with.

Comment: [According to Joel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112317/150562), there were over 3000 a month or two ago.  I doubt someone would hand tag that many posts.

Comment: Last year I [manually retagged about 1,300](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85582) questions over ~1 week, with the help of a greasemonkey script.  It'd certainly be possible to do twice that, especially with a team.  However, given the number of questions, I'd really expect someone to have checked in with meta first.

Comment: @AnnaLear I actually re-tagged somewhere between 300-600 questions (IIRC).  The 3K+ number was accurate at the time the statement was made but declined steadily because of a number of people who took it upon themselves but not all coordinated (some might have been, I was not a part of an "official" movement).

Comment: Please see [Let's Ban the ASP Tag on StackOverflow!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/lets-ban-the-asp-tag-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Indeed, it's the very first link in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consider "Dev-Only" solutions like blacklisting the tag to be a last-resort proposition.  Developers should spend most of their time on developing, not on tag support.

`ASP` should *not* be blacklisted, as it has an actual meaning; it is `Classic ASP`, and there will still be an occasional classic ASP question. I favor the synonym solution, with [classic-asp](/questions/tagged/classic-asp) as the master tag.

Comment: What proportion of users use [tag:asp] to mean Classic ASP? If it's a small minority, then no matter what the “proper” meaning of ASP is, the [tag:asp] tag should not mean Classic ASP.

Comment: Given the community's current desire to use highly-specific tags, users should be using [asp-classic] anyway.  The synonym will direct them to [asp-classic], at which time they can either choose it, or pick a more appropriate tag such as [asp.net]

Comment: Of the dozen or so questions that I edited `asp` out of on Friday, all but two were for Classic.  Given that someone has added the synonym, I'm going to mark this as accepted.

Comment: Questions tagged at one point with [tag:asp] seem to have [relatively evenly ended up](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59254) with [tag:asp.net] or [tag:asp-classic] one way or the other (keeping in mind that the query doesn't imply that [tag:asp] was necessarily *replaced*), so the synonym seems fine.