# Remove change tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Can [change](/questions/tagged/change) be deleted?

The tag is a way too broad/generic to ever be useful.
It can be used for basically everything that involves a change, and most things involve a change of some sort, or people wouldn't have a question about it.

**Update**

Ok I started deleting the [change](/questions/tagged/change), however on some occasions I found question where something like [change] is kinda justified. For example for javascript question regarding the onchange-event. I suggest we just retag those to the more descriptive [onchange](/questions/tagged/onchange).

If anybody is willing to help me get rid of the [change](/questions/tagged/change) that would be great.

Comment: elaborate please why it is useles

Comment: It's not November yet!

Comment: @Pekka I don't get it.

Comment: @PeeHaa it was meant as an (admittedly very obscure) reference to the November 2012 US General election and Obama's rather bleak-looking outlook. Although the way it looks like at the moment, he might win by default

Comment: It might be renamed to `jquery-change` to reference questions regarding the jQuery change event - there are already tags for `jquery-load` and `jquery-click` events. Then we just need to separate the wheat from the chaff . :)

Comment: Agreed: burninate away.

Answer (score 8):

I'm all for this.  My recommendation is that you rally the community to help you with it.

Considering that [the `asp` tag at one time had 3K+ questions on it and the community took it on itself to retag all the questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119037/whered-the-asp-tag-go-and-why-did-it-come-back), a [tag with *only* ~970 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change) would be easy to retag.

That said, I'd retag all the questions, (ask for help in the [Posse comitatus chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus) if you want) and then post a request to blacklist the tag when it's been removed from all of the questions (these kind of requests tend to go over better when the retagging work has been done to insure that questions with no tags will remain).

Note that if a tag was removed from all questions and doesn't reappear on any questions after a day (IIRC) will be considered "new" and subject to rep requirements for creating it so *some* users won't be able to use that tag after the retagging takes place.