# Blacklist [change]

Tags: discussion, tags

Can the [change](/questions/tagged/change) tag please be blacklisted?

[Remove change tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119335/remove-change-tag)

There aren't any questions anymore with that tag. But it tends to return everyday.

Comment: Cannot be created anymore since [tag:changes] exists.