# Remove [changed] and [changing]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[changed](/questions/tagged/changed) and [changing](/questions/tagged/changing) should be removed for the same reasons [[change] was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119335/remove-change-tag).

Comment: Go for it. ....