# About ASP tagging problems on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags

I have been contributing to Stack Overflow for some time, and I have noted a particular situation with ASP tags ([ASP-Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages), [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), etc). Very often the questions in ASP-Classic aren't related in any way to classic ASP. These questions are in the ASP.NET realm.

I can't figure a solution for this, because it seems like the OPs don't know what ASP Classic means or are just being lazy and tag the thing that comes in search. Every day I have to retag an average of 3,4 questions, and this is just me.

I don't know if this is a problem that needs more attention, but it's certainly a little tiring reminding the users that their questions are not related to ASP Classic and retag it correctly. How can I better deal with this situation?

Comment: For history, see: [Let's Ban the \[ASP\] Tag on StackOverflow!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84175/135887) and [Where'd the \[asp\] tag go, and why did it come back?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119037/135887), where the actual [tag:asp] vs [tag:asp-classic] vs [tag:asp.net] thing was resolved once and for all... *or was it*?

Comment: well, the reality is this is far from being resolved, it's resilent.

Comment: I believe it has to do with how the tag autocomplete suggestions are sorted. If you type "asp", "asp-classic" is displayed before "asp.net". This + laziness + lack of attention + lack of knowledge = mess.

Comment: Let's make [ASP-Classic] a synonym of [ASP-Clbuttic]. Maybe that would help.

Comment: for history & related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/classic-re-tag-discussion-on-some-good-ole-asp-classic

Comment: A thankless ASP, eh? Poor cleopatra.

Comment: Still a problem - though I have the opposite issue. I regularly run through 6-8 questions tagged asp-classic that should be asp.net...

Comment: @AnonJr i'm still having this problem but i don't find any suitable solution to this :/, i would prefer that any moderator say their opinnin about the problem. And to add more to this problem like a week ago i retagged a question didn't related with [asp-classic] tag, passed the edit and seconds later someone rettagged again with asp-classic. what a mess!!