# The Stack Overflow 'as' tag is very ambiguous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [as](/questions/tagged/as) tag can refer to the `As` keyword in VB.NET, the [Unix assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_%28Unix%29), [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) and possibly many other things. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by manually editing every tag to make it much clearer. Such as when used with Adobe AS3, it should probably be AS3 not AS. It would require a human to go through a validate all the tags.

Comment: Suppose I'm going to do that. Are there specific guidelines?

Comment: @Phonon: Ensure it makes sense. Make sure whatever you change `as` to be, that it actually pertains to the question. We don't want to create new problems!

Comment: @Phonon - see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26870/25163