# Should we close the 'as' tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request, ambiguous-tags

Relating to the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96054/164212)  I asked earlier, I've gone through all stackoverflow questions tagged with [as](/questions/tagged/as) and retagged them, because the tag is very ambiguous (see link to question above). In the process I realized that none of the questions needed the tag, because all of them really meant something else and there was another tag to replace it. As a result, the [as](/questions/tagged/as) tag is now empty. Should we close it? I personally don't have enough reputation to vote on it, but I think this would avoid a lot of confusion in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two letter tag doesn't seem a good tag, anyway, as it could be used in different contexts, with different meanings.

Blocking it seems a little excessive. We should decide to use the tag in just a case, and report the correct meaning of the tag in its wiki. If the tag doesn't have a wiki, and it's used in different contexts with different meanings, then it would get misused.

Comment: I agree completely, however there isn't a primary purpose it is used for, it's just a soup of things that abbreviate to a.s. and questions related to [tag:as-keyword]. I don't really know how one could pick a single correct meaning for it. I'm not sure this could simply be done on whim.

Comment: @Phonon If it's not possible to assign a primary purpose to the tag, then I agree that it should be blocked. As I said, a two letters tag easily gets misused, as it could be used for many acronyms, or tool names.

Comment: Is there a way for me to encourage a vote on that? I don't personally have enough reputation.

Comment: @Phonon Blocking a tag to avoid that it is used again is not something the moderators can do. This requires somebody part of the SE team.