# Why does the "not-programming-related" tag exists, if these questions aren't allowed on SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

If not programming related questions aren't allowed on SO, why don't you erase the `not-programming-related` tag?

Answer (score 6):

The "problem" is two-fold:

a) the tag exists so will get suggested if people start typing

b) even if it was successfully removed there's nothing to stop someone reinventing the tag.

We have talked about having a [tag blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list), but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, that tag will make the tag [blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list).