# Style tags by concept?

Tags: discussion, tags

I finally found the [tag folksonomy blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) and it was helpful in trying to understand the zeitgeist of tags.  I think some of the information could be incorporated into the [suggest tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) pages. I was thinking about a synonym between **motorola** and **freescale**.  That may be wrong for many other reasons, but I decided why the heck should I try to improve these tags.  What do business concepts have to do with *programming*?

The [redesigned tag page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) describes tags as a map.  This is opposed to the [folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) idea on the other blog entry.  So what kind of **map** do we have?  Topographical, road, political, climate, economic, food production, etc are all types of maps.  Should the tags only be about *programming*?  I see tags that are,

- *business* oriented. [motorola](/questions/tagged/motorola)  [freescale](/questions/tagged/freescale).
- problem domains. [phonenumbers](/questions/tagged/phonenumbers) [piechart](/questions/tagged/piechart)
- describe posters.  [student](/questions/tagged/student) [firsttime](/questions/tagged/firsttime)

and ones I find useful that are related to **programming concepts**.  I see that the *folksonomy* concept is good for organic growth and classification.  Could different classifications of tags have a different colour, font and/or box shape?  For some reason, the [**tag blacklist**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) is not a solution that was implemented.

Related: [Why tags without programming concepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30538/why-does-the-not-programming-related-tag-exists-if-these-questions-arent-all)

Comment: Your third category ("describe posters") should be destroyed on sight.

Comment: [tag:first-time] has 22 questions this year. How do you destroy it? Arg, sorry, I don't know what that tag is about.

Comment: An interesting idea, I think personally it would be distracting to me - your eyes are naturally drawn to colors, and lots of mini-rainbows on every question would be a bit overpowering IMO. Unless you show me a screenshot of a potential design, I would have to disagree with this.

Comment: The [*business* oriented concepts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful) are also not very constructive.  My motivation was to visually filter them out; getting rid of them is better.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than littering the question list with category identifiers, we already have lists where a user can seek out the types of questions they want to see. Not everyone wants to see a mashing together of all sorts of questions. So we allow users to create a list of tags they are interested in.

Perhaps this can be extended by allowing users to create multiple collections of tag-lists they're interested in.

Perhaps this can be extended to allow a sorting of questions by the asker's time on stackoverflow. I think that is an idea worth trying.

Comment: I wasn't meaning to create new *categories*.  I meant that existing tags could be *styled* based on a certain *taxonomy*; like *business line*, *problem domain*, or *programming language*, etc.  It doesn't make sense to tag a question with only **motorola**. I definitely do not want to **ADD** any boxes, etc.  Just a way to differentiate the existing tags.