# Is there a reason for "brand" tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I feel that the brand tags such as [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [adobe](/questions/tagged/adobe) can be misused and create too broad of questions.

Should we remove these or put more stern wiki text for them?

As LBT has noted, this has been brought up before? Can we make an effort to remove these for good?

Comment: Should we remove the [meta-tag:stackexchange] tag from Meta too?

Comment: @Oded i think if its used as a "general" purpose tag, then yes.

Comment: @Oded I would say yes, since almost all questions (anything not specific to stack overflow, which is most questions) should have it, and yet don't

Comment: Sigh. Tongue firmly and decisively removed from cheek by the Community.

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful.  FWIW, I spent a couple minutes a day removing the [Microsoft] tag from questions, but got bored after a few weeks of not getting anywhere.

Comment: C compilers can be distributed by many companies, so adding compiler's brand to the question, for example, seems legitimate to me. But that's just my two cents here, I'm not regular on SO so what do I know? ;)

Comment: @Mołot most of those compilers have names like borland-c, gcc or visual-c.

Comment: @DanielA.White consider adding this aspect directly to your question, then :)

Comment: @Mołot For a tag to be appropriate there would need to be questions for which the tag could be the only tag on the question.  That would never be the case in such an example.  It's a case where the information can be included in the question and doesn't need to be specifically in a tag.