# Remove tag [freescale]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

As per [Are company tag names useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful)?

Can we remove the tag [freescale](/questions/tagged/freescale)?

Comment: If it has no questions, it will be automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: @animuson Thanks.  I guess if 3:00 UTC passes, then I should delete this question.

Comment: ***`Burninate`*** it. Looks like an ad anyway.

Answer (score -1):

> Currently this tag has **no** questions associated  with it

Then it will be automatically removed [within the next 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40725/183757)

**Update**

> [image: All hail Trogdor!]

Comment: I guess I should have deleted the question before you posted the same answer that [animuson](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) left as a comment.  Your answer is a useless addition, -1.