# Should retagging make the source tag invalid?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I don't know exactly know how retagging works (if it's a manual process or if there's a specific feature for that) but shouldn't the source tag (the one that's being replaced) be disallowed?

I guess that if you retag you don't want people using that tag anymore.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's already a barrier to creating new tags: you need [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

So after a retag request for mssql, it will take a while before the tag rears its ugly head.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about that kind of retagging; I think he's talking about moderator mass retagging.

Comment: So am I, after you mass retag, the old tag will have 0 questions, and it takes 250 rep to recreate it

Comment: the tag is not deleted, it exists even though it belongs to 0 questions

Comment: @Juan Manual: One day after a mssql cleanup, the badge will be gone.  I guess it's some background process that runs at least once a day