# Tag Autorenaming

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement a Tag Black List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

I recently asked a question about [how to re-request a retage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32461/how-should-i-re-request-a-retag)

It stemmed from the fact that despite Visual-Studio-2008 being the preferred tag, VS2008 was still being used.

One of the comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27787/retag-vs2008-to-visual-studio-2008) mentions that "autorenaming" is better than tag aliasing. I'd agree with that.

I'd love to see a dictionary of unsuitable tags and their associated acceptable tag.

This list could be managed by either moderators or 10,000+ level users.

I'm not sure if the auto-rename should occur after the user types space or after they press submit. I think that it should display a notice mentioning that one of their tags was autorenamed.

Comment: This and the the tag synonyms are both planned already. The black list and synonyms will meet both your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stellar idea, but may be hard to implement and manage.

It would have to avoid cycles, and could even be limited to only one level (ie, you can't have an entry for VS --> Visual Studio if Visual Studio is not a 'root tag').

With a single level there can be no cycles, and while the table would have a lot of entries, it should be very quick as the "less desirable tag" is unique.

**Even more difficult to implement**

If you allowed multi level tags, though, it could be better used for search.

VS8 --> Visual-Studio-8 --> Visual Studio

Where both Visual-Studio-8 and Visual Studio are marked as root (ie, acceptable) tags.

Now if someone searches for Visual Studio in the search box, it might give the option to 'expand the search' and follow the tag dictionary outwards to Visual-Studio-8.