# Tutorial section for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tutorials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving a personal technical blog to stackoverflow / serverfault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault)

Many (most?) of the questions I've seen on Stack Overflow are specific to a narrowly-defined problem set, e.g., how-do-I-do-this, what-does-this-error-mean, etc.

Occasionally, a question comes along that is a little bit bigger in scope, such as how do I implement a simple client/server application using sockets or how do I create a Windows service.  Every now and again, I've taken the time to provide a detailed instruction set (see [answer to "Easiest language to create a Windows service in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803)) for questions like these.  And when I notice new questions that refer to the same or similar problem, I usually provide a link to the answer I've already given.

Would it be useful to the Stack Overflow community to have a tutorial section under one's profile that allows Stack Overflow participants to provide such tutorials without having to have a question asked?  In my mind, I'm envisioning something like [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) but completely hosted within the Stack Overflow environment.

Comment: you might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697095/where-do-you-submit-your-programming-articles-tutorials helpful. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a link in your profile to your blog would serve the same purpose.  You're also welcome to ask a question then provide the answer on those occasions when you have an answer ready but the question hasn't been asked yet.

Comment: Right.  I thought about the blog thing.  The thing is, I don't have a blog, and even if I did, *my* blog is not going to be read, not that that's the point.  As for asking a question and answering it, that would work, but then it gets lost in the shuffle of the other 400K questions that have been asked.

Comment: Matt, yes, but the ask/self-answer technique gets TREMENDOUS Google Juice.

Answer (score 10):

Let's see ...

StackOverflow, et al, are *question and answer* sites. They are not a blog engine. In fact, the format doesn't even work particularly well for blog-type entries. They do OK for questions you self-answer, but even that seems to be frowned on (these days) by the communities.

Having a separate tutorial/blog post kind of deal that any of us (even with a minimum required threshold) can post to will dilute the value of the primary mission (Q & A), whilst simultaneously increasing the amount of noise and maintenance on the site. Not to mention the development effort for Jeff & crew (who I'm sure many of us would like to see implement things like [tag blacklists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) first).

> In my mind, I'm envisioning something like CodeProject but completely hosted within the SO environment.

That exists already. It's called CodeProject.

Bottom line: The sites work right now because they're laser-focused on specific missions and have a critical mass of users. Adding more to their nice, focused missions will dilute their value, hurt the quality, and take development resources away from more pressing and mission-focused feature requests.