# Users should be able to store common answers/quotes/explanations to their profile

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

I'd like to have a place to store a few common explanations that apply to many answers--like why DRY is good or why you shouldn't optimize.

These apply to a bunch of answers, but re-writing them is getting nearly as annoying as reading them all the time.

I guess I'm suggesting a "Philosophy" section in each user profile where they can type out a few lines related to a topic.  You could browse it while looking at user profiles, or hyperlink directly to it from an answer.

It is possible to do this off-site through another web service or google docs, but that just doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33048/tutorial-section-for-stackoverflow-closed

Comment: I store mine in my profile. Look closely...

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't strike me as a server-side feature. If you have frequently-entered text that you would like to store, manage, and paste into answers, there are many, many plug-ins and applications that can do that for you:

[Clippings 3.1 for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1347) for example.

Answer (score 0):

We already have special content using the normal infrastructure. E.g.
[How Does Stack Overflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq/).

We could have the same for common explanations that apply to many answers. Only a little bit of consensus among us is required.

There should probably be one for each site (Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.)