# Should questions about buying software be flagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302444/where-to-buy-html-template

This question is asking about where to buy an HTML template. The answers provided are just website recommendations.

Is this considered a programming question or not? If it's not programming related, do I flag or do I retag?

Comment: Hopefully they don't shunt that to SU either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not flag; not retag.

If you do not believe that this is a programming questions, and have [at least 3000 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work), vote to close. That is the correct procedure.

To elaborate:

**Flag**

Flagging goes beyond the "vote to close" reasons.

- *"Offensive, Abusive, or Hate Speech"* - Does not seem to apply.
- *"Spam"* - Again, does not apply.
- *"Requires Moderator attention"* - If the community-moderation mechanisms are working, there is no need to flag a moderator. They are there to handle exceptional circumstances, not routine closing.

**Retag**

You *should not* ever retag a question to express your opinion about a question. Period. Tags like "should-be-on-*" or "not-programming-related" have [no place on any of these sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list).

Comment: Okay, am going to stop accidentally rewriting your answer.

Comment: Does that mean if I have less than 3000 rep, there is nothing I can do about this question? Also, let's say I did have more than 3k rep, do you think this would be an appropriate question to close?

Comment: @Mike Sherov - You can always leave a comment to express any meta-concerns you have about a post (clarification, requests for additional info, does not belong, etc). But, essentially, yes; different degrees of community moderation tools are left to those who have shown the experience (reputation) with the system to apply them properly. You are well on your way to getting 3000 rep.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My comment wasn't meant as a complaint, I just wanted to be sure that the appropriate thing to do was wait till 3k. Any thoughts on whether you'd vote to close this question, or others like it?

Comment: @Mike Sherov - I voted to close... although, I'm not 100% sure I was right. It *seemed* like the author was asking for a web product recommendation (inappropriate, no programming question). But, in actuality, what the author *really* wants is to see some source code examples (appropriate), even if they have to buy it. The question could have been worded more clearly. But that's why it takes five to close (and five can re-open it).

Answer (score 6):

I disagree about the use of flagging. In the past, <3K users have been encouraged to flag for moderator attention for questions that might deserve a close. I think, personally, that some close reasons and situations call for this more so than others, but I don't see any harm in it.

Heck, I've got 8K, and if I've used all my closes for the day (a frequent occurrence) and I see something really awful, I flag it.

*EDIT TO REFLECT CHANGE*

Now that we have the new 'close reason' flags, people without close votes are encouraged to use them to indicate close-worthy questions.