# Automatically replace "bad" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)
>   [Implement a Tag Black List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

Some tags should be automatically replaced by other tags whenever a question is posted or retagged. This should be a manually maintained list of replacements that is applied automatically. Without that, all retag requests are pointless:

- `[as3]` [was retagged to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/2853#2853) `[actionscript-3]`, has again [552 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3)
- `[macosx]` [was retagged to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/please-could-we-combine-the-osx-and-macosx-tags) `[osx]`, has again [513 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macosx)
- `[aws]` [was retagged to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/combine-aws-tag-and-amazon-web-services) `[amazon-web-services]`, has again [37 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws)
- `[db]` [was retagged to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4849/move-db-db-design-tag) `[database]`, has again [52 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db)
- `[rails]` is constantly being retagged to `[ruby-on-rails]`, but has again [41 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails)

Just look through old retag requests for more examples.

If it is decided for a tag that mass-retagging it to another tag is ok, it should also be safe to extend this to new questions asked in the future. If somebody later tries to post a question with a "bad" tag, that tag should automatically be replaced with the "fixed" tag.

Comment: Actually rails was fixed, you're just looking at the old cache.

Comment: Functional Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list

Comment: I think this is the actual duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms

Comment: @Lance: Well, then wait a day or two and there will be twenty new "rails" questions :). Also I think automatic replacement is not the same as the blacklist proposed in the question you linked to.

Comment: @sth - Tag synonyms (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) accomplishes the same thing but avoids all the "where did my tag go?" questions... and the "color" vs "colour" wars. Let users enter the tags they prefer and let search match all the equivalent tags behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jon: Full-blown tag synonyms with adjusted UI in the tag suggestion box etc. like in the linked question would IMHO be more than really needed. A simple automatic replacement list like I'd suggest should also be much more easy to implement.