# Add the ability to flag a tag for moderator review

Tags: feature-request, tags, flags

I think it might be useful to allow flagging directly on a tag.

[image: Tag with flag]

This could be used to indicate that a given tag should be merged with another one. While we already [have a way to discuss tags that should be merged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request), sometimes they reappear.

There could also be a way to automatically fill out a [**[retag-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request)**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/retag-request) question.

[image: Flagged tag]

Answer (score 8):

I think posting a question on meta (as we do now) is sufficient.

As for them reappearing, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) is aimed to solve that

Comment: +1 There are times when community input on a tag-merge request has brought something up that made the request a bad idea

Comment: **+1** That would *reduce* the use of a flag on a tag. I mainly asked the question for the second part though, having a way to automatically fill out a **[retag-request]** There might also be other reasons for flagging a tag, which we won't find out until we have that ability.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just flag the questions and write that it is the [foo] tag that concerns you?

Comment: this seems far more sensible