# Re-tagging suggestion: Combine the 68000 and mc68000 tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've gone through all the questions (currently 30) with the tags [mc68000](/questions/tagged/mc68000) and [68000](/questions/tagged/68000) and they're all(*) concerned with the the [Motorola 68000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000) processor.

I would have [flagged it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40828/add-the-ability-to-flag-a-tag-for-moderator-review) or a added a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89576/flag-synonym-suggestion-for-moderator) (I don't have enough answers), but it seems like the way to go is to suggest it here, so I'd like to suggest combining these tags. Even though 68000 seems to be more popular (and has a small wiki) I'd suggest mc68000 (or even better m(c)68k) as the name, as it is more specific (I'd consider these roughly analogous to 386, i386 and x86, but I'm open to suggestions).

(*) A few posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797400/assembly-6800-looping-testing-specific-bits-in-a-word)), I'm not 100% certain about, but they all have discussion about the issue in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth combining with [coldfire](/questions/tagged/coldfire) too then - it's the same processor core with microcontroller features.

Comment: I disagree; the Coldfire processors are still in production and the questions with this tag are about implementation problems.  The MC68000 is obsolete, but frequently used for teaching assembly language and most of this tag's questions are about homework.

Comment: I understand the objection, and will bow to popular opinion, but it's still the same instruction set. There are currently 13 questions tagged coldfire on the main site, so it probably makes sense to give low-volume tags a slightly wider audience