# Tag removal request

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-block-request

Yes, I would like for the tag [cake](/questions/tagged/cake) to be removed from Stack Overflow. Someone decided to actually create a [cake](/questions/tagged/cake) tag due to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420689/surprise-for-a-programmer and my predictions of newbies getting [cake](/questions/tagged/cake) and [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) confused are already happening.

For instance, that tag was made yesterday and already there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424890/cakephp-app-authentication-wordpress-authentication which was originally tagged [cake](/questions/tagged/cake) instead of [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp)

So I request either the removal of the tag altogether, or making it so that the tag can only be used by moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 28, [cake](/questions/tagged/cake) is a synonym of [cake-php](/questions/tagged/cake-php):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp/synonyms

It's been invoked 11 times in the interim, so it appears that your fears were well-founded.

Answer (score 2):

That's the only question with the tag [cake](/questions/tagged/cake), I don't see it's a major problem IMO

It would be if there was a lot of [cake-php](/questions/tagged/cake-php) wrongly tagged questions, but there isn't.

Comment: This is because I retagged that question. Read my question. It mentions a question asked by a 1 rep user. That question was tagged `cake` before I saw it and corrected it to `cakephp` and the tag has only existed for 24 hours. I say it's just better to avoid the retagging mess later..

Comment: ok, but re-tagging 1 question is not such a big mess

Comment: besides, it's not possible to ban tags (yet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018)

Comment: Yes, but it was one question for 24 hours. So in a month or two it'll be 30-60 questions tagged wrongly. And I'm not saying ban the tag, I'm saying make it so that it doesn't exist and it takes a 200-rep user to create the tag again.

Comment: and one partial solution would be to remove the tag from that question, and it will get deleted in the batch nightly job

Comment: @Downvoter, I wasn't sure if the tag would still show up when you make a question.. and plus I think it should be decided if it needs to be removed.. I think it should be, but maybe the community thinks otherwise?

Comment: @ear, if a tag is in no questions, it gets deleted within 24 hours. But nothing prevents it from being re-created, see my previous link

Answer (score 0):

I removed all tags but [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) from that question - it'll disappear soon. Next time, if a tag is bothering you, and you want it removed or change -go change it, you're way over the requisite rep for retagging.

Comment: A valiant effort, but the cake tag has already been removed and re-added once in that question's history... the matter may not be so easily settled ... (evil laugh)

Answer (score 0):

If someone decides to roll back that edit, we could always go with the tag [birthday-cake](/questions/tagged/birthday-cake). Then there would be no confusion.

Edit: I noticed the question got rolled back, so I did what I said above.

Comment: ...and I went back to cake. Cake is so much simpler and like the top voted answer says - there aren't wrongly tagged cake-php questions or anything. if it becomes a problem, we can still retag it.

Comment: @Epaga: Did you read the comments on the answer below?

Comment: yes i did. and i so don't feel like discussing this any more, so you win. ;) so much for having my cake and eating it too.