# Do not migrate restricted/moderator-only tags with a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/why-am-i-getting-welcome-to-stack-overflow-visit-your-user-page-to-set-your-nam) was just migrated from SO, and it brought the restricted `[faq]` tag with it.  Now no one but a moderator can remove this tag.

Restricted tags* should be stripped from the question when it is migrated.

*<sub>And blacklisted tags, when [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) is implemented in 6 to 8 weeks</sub>

Comment: I agree, this seems highly automatable, but for now you can flag these for moderator attention.  Particularly here on meta where you can't swing a dead cat by the tail without hitting a moderator.

Comment: I'm tempted to create a silly feature request, mark it status-completed, and wait for it to be migrated... sadly, I know better

Comment: @Bill: I object to your abusive connotations towards my species!!!11!!!!oneoneone

Comment: @Ether: Whoops!  That was a poor choice of expression, given your gravatar.  Please don't hold this slip of my forked tongue against all members of *my* scaly species!!!! ;)

Comment: @Bill: no worries; I eat your kind for breakfast. :D

Comment: @Æether, what did I tell you? Bad kitty, bad! [Leave that mod on the ground](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2LWLC59CNM&feature=related)!

Comment: Refuse to upvote, even if I support this suggestion. You could at least have cleaned that question up, lazy furball!

Comment: @Lady, [what](http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/2001878703063990209_rs.jpg)?

Comment: this reminds me of all the questions that get migrated from SO to SU and immediately closed as offtopic.  this is automatable, sure, but how big a problem is it?  if you notice a question with this problem, flag for moderator attention so the errant tag can be removed.

Comment: @quack: I did flag the question for moderator attention (Bill the Lizard came by immediately afterward and removed the tag and closed the question). However I can't imagine he'd enjoy doing that repeatedly, hence this bug report for the general case.

Comment: @Lady: what is it that you feel I should have done for the question? I *did* try to edit out the [faq] tag, which is how I discovered that it wasn't possible and led me to file this bug report. I also flagged it as a dupe, *and* left a snarky comment for Jonathan regarding his answer. I'm not sure what else I could have done :)

Comment: @Furball: Look and learn:
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/46655/revisions

Comment: @Ether, the small-font link you gave is actually marked `[status-completed]` now... I know it isn't, exactly, but it looks weird.

Comment: @Lady: *baffled expression*

Comment: @Ether: Waffles are nice!

Answer (score 1):

Great suggestion - no need to overwhelm the mods :)

This will be deployed either tonight or in tomorrow's push.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting Community user drop all the moderator-only tags and add `support` tag as new revision, once a question is migrated to meta.