# The string "faq" is removed from a tag of migrated question, even if the tag is not [faq]

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tags

Restricted/moderator tags like `[faq]` are [stripped when migrating to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46659/do-not-migrate-restricted-moderator-only-tags-with-a-question), but it seems to be too aggressive.

In the question [*Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026307/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag?noredirect=1), there was originally a `[c++-faq]` tag. When it is [migrated to here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/68647/revisions), however, the tag becomes `[c++-]` (see revision 1). Is it intended?

Comment: +1 This could go either way. I'm very interested to hear Jeff's answer.

Comment: Also, I'm curious if a tag like `[faq-xyz]` would be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and deployed - thanks for finding!

Comment: @Jon that's pretty much it :)