# How can we propose a tag to be included in the blacklist?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, blocked-tags

According to Jeff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list/49418#49418), there is a tag blacklist only devs can access.

Can we help selecting this tags?
Should we post a meta question tagged blacklist-request or bl-request for the team to consider?

Would this be useful at all?

Comment: [blacklist-request] seems better than [bl-request].

Comment: A blacklist request tag should include "tag" so it's searchable.

Comment: A potential duplicate from 2014 (which has an answer from a then-CM): [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast good catch, thanks.

Comment: @V2Blast Given your recent edits here (Q&A), was there a reason not to also change "blacklist"➞"blocklist"? I'm not a fan of wholesale editing all Q&A just to make that change, but it seems reasonable to do it when you're already making other edits.

Comment: @Makyen: My edit to this question was just a tag edit (to add the relevant [blocked-tags] tag) – I didn't even think about that. (And my edit to the answer was just to ensure people didn't think they should be emailing mods.) But given that this question's already closed as a dupe of the other one, I don't think there's a particular need to update its phrasing...?

Comment: @Makyen the official announcement by Yaakov said they're just changing their official pages, e.g. Help Center, and leaving the Q&A edits to local mods and members. If someone wants, they can make such edits, personally I see no need to as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the linked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list/49418#49418):

> We work with the existing site moderators to determine what's bad enough to be blacklisted. It has to be quite bad.

That's pretty clear, actually.  Contact the mod team and/or post here on Meta if you think something's bad enough to warrant blacklisting.

As noted in Jeff's post, the dev team actually handles the implementation.  You need to convince the moderators of a site that a tag needs to be blacklisted; then they will request its addition from the dev team.

Comment: Seems like a straightforward enough process, right? *Sigh...*

Comment: @alex: layers on layers on layers.  it's like an onion....

Comment: I know, I was just proposing a way for us mere mortals to help. Post a request, discuss, vote on it, and if approved, moderators or dev team can implement it.

Comment: @Downvoter: you tagged this question *[discussion]* not *[feature-request]* ... just consider this post an overview of the current process.  :)