# What is Stack Exchange's official stance on words such as "black list", "white list", "master", "slave", and so on?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, policy, code-of-conduct

I've just had one of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329742/removing-object-properties-with-lodash/40339196#40339196) edited on Stack Overflow to swap out "black list" and "white list" for "deny list" and "allow list" respectively. There was no comment on the change, but I assume it to be due to those words being racially charged.

I don't mind the change (except for the introduced grammar mistakes), but I do feel like "white list" and "black list" convey my point in a clearer way and so makes my answer more useful to the wider community.

I am going to leave the edit (but fix the grammar mistake), but I am interested to know moving forward how we should be framing our questions/answers, and if there were a list of words we should now substitute? I feel like this is a can of worms, especially regarding any networking (master/slave) or Git (master) questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1500/discussion-on-question-by-chris-what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-word).

Comment: Wow ridiculous thread. Then how about words like  "white noise", "black out", "brown out reset", "black body radiation", "black matter" etc etc etc ... norms of this century is a joke lol....

Answer (score 48, accepted):

We would like to endorse and expand on the [answer already given by curiousdannii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350884/51):

> …inasmuch as Stack Overflow and the other technology sites form a sort of documentation of technology, I don't think that there can be any blanket ban on such terminology. Many technology projects have used these terms and you cannot have useful or clear documentation or explanations of these projects if it is forbidden to use the terminology used by those projects.
>
> As projects change one-by-one to avoid these terms, especially if there is a general consensus to do so (which I think will probably happen for a term like 'slave' but I think it's likely will not happen for 'blacklist'), then there will be a reduction in how many posts use these terms here. But as questions can be asked about older technology it will remain a fact of life that these terms will continue to be used here.

We are not going to institute any sort of network ban on the use of these terms, and will leave it in the hands of the moderators and the Community to decide on the appropriate usages of these terms on the different sites throughout the network, both for new content, and for legacy content. If there are changes that we can facilitate making once communities have decided how to act, we are available to assist with that.

As curiousdannii points out and expresses so well, without a generally accepted replacement for a given term, enforcing a general ban will end up in rendering large swatches of documentation and content useless. If and when the terminology changes for a given technology, then the Community will no doubt adopt the new terminology as the new standard for use on the network when talking about that technology. But without this consensus (and the definition of an obvious replacement that is accepted by the community that is the expert on that technology), we feel that an indiscriminate ban on these terms would be inappropriate.

With that said, we are definitely sensitive to the ways in which specific pieces of terminology — which at one time were common and standard in a given technological context — can themselves be offensive and hurtful to different minority groups. And we admit that there is always work to be done in this area. Though removing and adjusting such offensive terminology is itself not an ultimate solution, and should not be used as [a replacement for more meaningful actions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/10/stack-overflows-stand-against-racism-blm/) taken to show solidarity with marginalized groups, this does not mean that this is not a meaningful act unto itself.

For these reasons, we believe that continued use of master/slave and blacklist and whitelist terms should be discouraged wherever possible. In that vein, we would like to announce that we have made the following changes on all user-facing portions of the sites:

- We can confirm that no instances of master/slave are shown in the UI
- All instances of “blacklist” have been converted to “blocklist”
- All instances of “whitelist” have been converted to “allowlist”

These changes affect any text showing up in the user interface, in server logs, on mod pages, on dev routes and dev-pages, and we will work to ensure that these terms will no longer be used moving forward for any new feature work. Additionally, from this point forward, we will use the term “blocklists” instead of “blacklists” when handling requests to block tags, words in titles, and usernames from appearing on the site. We are planning to update the relevant tags on metas network-wide (and will update here when this has been done) and will continue to update our usage of this terminology internally as it becomes feasible to do so.

We thank you in your advance for your continued support and sensitivity towards these important issues.

Comment: Thanks @Yaakov Ellis . The outcome is more than what I expected to see as a result of my question but appreciate the detailed research, analysis and response. I've updated my answer to use allowlist/blocklist (just wanted to mention, despite being completely minor compared to the network-wide changes you've made)

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here: https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/h8w36t/github_will_no_longer_use_the_term_master_as/fuuf948/

Comment: @ZoeTheLockdownPrincess also https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/866ynp/what_are_the_origins_of_the_words_blacklist_and/dw3svkw/

Comment: `For these reasons, we believe that continued use of master/slave and blacklist and whitelist terms should be discouraged wherever possible. In that vein, we would like to announce that we have made the following changes on all user-facing portions of the sites` Would it make sense to reflect that decision here https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/ ? And perhaps have a mention in the CoC?

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a look at anywhere you use the ["grandfather clause"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_clause), a term which has explicitly racist origins. We've switched to using "legacy clause" as an alternative.

Comment: "We can confirm that no instances of master/slave are shown in the UI" Hm. The "[master-slave]" tag still exists. It's noted as deprecated, but still, it can be found and used.

Comment: My statement in the post is talking about the website itself. Individual sites can still make their own decisions and rules about how to treat user of these terms when it comes to content and tags.

Comment: "With that said, we are definitely sensitive to the ways in which specific pieces of terminology — which at one time were common and standard in a given technological context — can themselves be offensive and hurtful to different minority groups." Seeing as how there is no reasonable basis for such offense, I do not understand how it's possible to have such a sensitivity.

Answer (score 58):

While we wait for an official stance to be explained, I'll say that inasmuch as Stack Overflow and the other technology sites form a sort of documentation of technology, I don't think that there can be any blanket ban on such terminology. Many technology projects have used these terms and you cannot have useful or clear documentation or explanations of these projects if it is forbidden to use the terminology used by those projects.

As projects change one-by-one to avoid these terms, especially if there is a general consensus to do so (which I think will probably happen for a term like 'slave' but I think it's likely will not happen for 'blacklist'), then there will be a reduction in how many posts use these terms here. But as questions can be asked about older technology it will remain a fact of life that these terms will continue to be used here.

For the specific post and edit your raised, I would be asking what the official Lodash documentation says. Does it use the terms 'blacklist' and 'whitelist'? If so, then so should you. If not (or if it changed terminology recently), then at the moment I think it should probably be up to the post's author what terminology to use. I do not think the common vernacular has reached any clear alternative to 'blacklist/whitelist' yet. While it's still common to talk about rental or credit card 'blacklists' I don't think we should be moving to ban them from computing. But if you like the terms 'denylist' or 'blocklist' more, then go for it! But I think you should also consider explaining what that means, because it will not be as easily understood as the idiomatic term 'blacklist' would be.

(I think it's much more likely for the term 'slave' to be retired from computing because it was never a particular apt metaphor in the first place. What does it mean for a database to be a 'slave'? For it to be readonly? For it to be controlled by another server? Maybe, maybe not, it depends on the technology and how it's set up. And I can't think of non-computing contexts where this metaphor is used. So I think it's likely that 'master/slave' technology will be replaced with things like 'master/replica', where the metaphor is more clearly connected to the non-computing uses like the master of a record from which other copies are replicated.)

Comment: "*I would be asking what the official Lodash documentation says. Does it use the terms 'blacklist' and 'whitelist'?*" for what it's worth Lodash doesn't use such terms but nor does it use anything to denote whether a list"a list for rejected/accepted" stuff. It stays neutral by just having lists of stuff (documented as `paths`) and mentioning that `_.omit` takes the list out ("blacklisting"/"reject listing"), while `_.pick` only keeps the list ("whitelisting"/"allow listing"). That's been the case for quite a while but I suspect it's done for uniformity of documentation reasons and terseness.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, I did actually read the Lodash docs after I wrote this, and that style of docs indicates why the supplementary documentation of Stack Overflow Q&As can be so helpful. If you're familiar with Lodash it would make lots of sense, but if you aren't it might be hard to decode. For answers here I think authors should be able to clarify how it works using natural conventional language, which I think includes the use of a term like "blacklist", and probably will include that term for quite a while longer.

Comment: Yes, Lodash documentation tends to be quite terse. It's quite helpful if you actually know what you need, since it conveys essential information in few words but probably not as useful when you're not certain in that. It's designed to serve more as a quick reference - a step above just "cheat sheet" style.

Comment: There is definitely going to be a problem if there would be a blanket ban. A somewhat random example: [electronics.SE has 969 posts about I2C slaves](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bi2c%5D+slave). The terminology is part of a standard that's decades old and it's hardly the only standard in which slaves are used. Enforcing a blanket ban would cripple communications as long as the standards are what they are.

Comment: @Mast See also [Another term for “Master Slave”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/204357/9548)

Comment: Not to mention pretty much any object language supports method chaining and there are plenty of data binding libraries out there too. And I don't think we have a replacement name for either.

Comment: I'm gonna call out "idiomatic understanding" of blacklist vs blocklist/denylist. Just because it's been in your language use for years doesn't make it idiomatic ("using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker") to a newcomer. There are a lot of native speakers of English that don't know what a blacklist is, but if you said "deny list" they would immediately understand the language. Just because our use of language is wrong doesn't mean we should by rote continue to use it that way.

Comment: @jcolebrand `There are a lot of native speakers of English that don't know what a blacklist is` citation. I know the verb "to blacklist" (*will blacklist*, *blacklists*, *blacklisted*, *blacklisting* etc.) and the noun "blacklist", I would not use "deny list" ever as a verb e.g. "denying list" or "denylisting"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA should I just run a poll through quinnipiac? I have all of the resources to formalize what I know from anecdotal conversation with people that no, a lot of native speakers do not in fact know what the term blacklist is. You think they do because you do. Additionally, what is wrong with "denylisting a person who wants to apply for a job @ X"? It absolutely connotes the same thing. This feels like a fight looking for a moment. The words simply are not idiomatic, they are contextually learned.

Comment: For what it's worth, the use of "master/slave" terminology in technical fields [is attested since 1904](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236752849_Broken_Metaphor_The_Master-Slave_Analogy_in_Technical_Literature). The underlying metaphor is of control originating from another device of the same type, rather than the same controller. This being somehow "racist" comes across as a psychological projection of the American collective unconsciousness. People from other countries don't associate slavery with race except insofar as exposure to the American education system taught them to.

Comment: "Additionally, what is wrong with "denylisting a person who wants to apply for a job @ X"?" This is a very strange form of argument, which is why I'm confused that I see it so often. Somehow, the fact that *language is understood descriptively rather than prescriptively* is supposed to *justify consciously and artificially changing it* - rather than providing evidence for why this doesn't actually work, most people will ignore your efforts, and people who do go along are likely to resent you for it. Yes, words "are contextually learned" - that is **exactly why** the old terms will stick!

Comment: (...and why the attempt to resist that fact, comes across as suggestive of a profound authoritarian impulse.)

Answer (score 34):

Any policy in this effect should also take into consideration non native English persons (many with very weak knowledge).

A "blacklist" is a very common word and has been translated directly into other languages and therefore the English version is easily understandable.

A "banlist" is not so common and therefore requires extra cognitive work to understand.

Also the other way - a translation from other languages directly to English will suddenly be bombarded that a "naughty" word has been used.

Also for example the word "master" (as a technical term) has been directly incorporated into some languages.

Comment: +1. add to that, a master is, in many useful contexts and in general, an entity that masters (accomplishes, sees to get accomplished, controls to a good end, etc) something, **not** a person feeling entitled to unduly commanding or harrassing others, whether selectively or not. Mixing these up is a fallacy. Discrimination also goes two ways - as in claiming discrimination used as a weapon against well-meaning other persons fully within their rights (and others'), and has been seen to be very capable of terrorizing by threatening censorship and punishment. Assume Good Faith exists for a reason.

Comment: What's the distinction then between master (sees to get accomplished, in control, authority) and principal (first in order of importance, main; _also_ the person with the highest authority, most important person in an organization or group)? Is there a useful definition of master that is not also met by principal or authoritative? Your account is 53 days old, so I can't tell where your experience lies, but so far your profile seems to be around acceptable word usage and substitution to best fit a given scenario. Hopefully then you can use that expertise to explain to me here?

Comment: Hear, hear. Just today I learned, from another comment ITT, that some people might take issue with the term "grandfather clause". I am a native English speaker, a natural-born Canadian citizen, in my forties, and well educated; and not only had I never heard of such a thing, but the notion still strikes me as absurd after reading the Wikipedia article. If *I* could potentially run into trouble because of something like this, ESL speakers outside of North America surely don't stand a chance.

Comment: @Karl To fully understand that "grandfather clause" article, and the literacy tests associated with voting rights, it's important to know that [Anti-literacy laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-literacy_laws_in_the_United_States) in many slave states before and during the American Civil War *prohibited* teaching slaves to read and write.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that; and I understood it before reading the article a year ago; it did not, and still does not, affect my impression that the notion is absurd. What you are missing here is that I have a general principle that historical atrocities *do not and cannot* directly make words bad to use, no matter how severe the atrocity. Words that are bad to use, are bad because of *deliberate* subtexts underlying them, not because they simply have some etymological allusion to someone else's bad acts. *Especially* not one that's unknown to the speaker.

Answer (score -37):

Another "while we are waiting" answer: embrace change.

In the end, these are just *terms* that denote something some more complicated concept.

Yes:

- It is *inconvenient* to come up with new terms that "work", and it takes time before a broad enough consensus will be found.
- It costs a certain amount of time and energy to adapt to that.

But at some point, you have adapted, and it will not matter any more to you that you used different terms some time back.

And especially in larger organisations, there is **no** way to avoid adapting. At least in such places, your option space consists of: accepting what is asked from you, or to ignore it, inadvertently leading to massive conflicts with your management.

And in case you consider such efforts to be completely ridiculous, I suggest you spend a few minutes watching "Malcom X" learn about the usage of the words black and white (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PycgpyPd9E)).

Now: stackoverflow is a community that millions of people turn to. Thus it is primed for coming up with such new terms, and coming to a consensus for new terms.

From that point of view, SE Inc. has two options:

- trying to be on the side that *defines* how change look like
- or to play catch-up with what others are doing

Pick your favorite choice.

My suggestion: when people are writing up new content, there could be some sort of mechanism *suggesting* them alternative terms. Don't make it mandatory to use them, **but** support those who are open about this topic.

Comment: Question is where does it end? Anyone can find anything offensive. We need to draw the line somewhere. Marking words as offensive when used in totally unrelated contexts and meaning will lead us nowhere. Also it will not really change real underlying problems. If some company/individual want's to use different words, that is fine, but blanket banning and bullying others into meaningless changes is completely different story.

Comment: My company has put up an internal search engine. They suggest to use blocklist and to not use blacklist when writing new code/specs. And while you folks here wonder about the purity of language, I have the choice between using blocklist instead of blacklist or risking a conflict with my management. About blocklist or blacklist. I draw lines. Where they matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (the downvotes seem a little harsh?). I'm totally up for embracing change. In fact, that is why I am asking for a list of words I should lean towards when writing questions/answers in future. If I didn't want to embrace it I could've simply edited the answer back to my original wording.

Comment: *"these are just terms"* Exactly, those are merely technical terms. Changing them doesn't make a significant positive change on anything, IMO.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Opinion, not fact. Honesty: I am not convinced that it will have a big positive effect. But: it drives discussion. It gets people to **think** about language, it gets people to think about their mindset and internalized views. Change always begins when people start thinking about stuff they never thought about before. We should set a timer and come back in 5 or 10 years, then we might be able to assess what positive and negative things came out of such ideas.

Comment: @Chris I didnt expect much else (regarding the downvotes). For me, this is really pragmatical: either I use my creativity to come with good new terms, or I would spent the next months and years clashing into people. From my point of view: freedom is about the ability to say what you think. Which words I use ... doesn't matter much.

Comment: "embrace the change" is directly colliding with "ability to say what you think". When rename Git master branch movement started, I was not exactly thrilled, but I was almost caught into "what does it cost me" rhetoric. But then in my Twitter feed started popping things like "let's use this as signal for HR to reeducate/fire people" and similar bullying, some coming from prominent developers. And this was huge red flag for me. I don't need to wait 5-10 years to see where this is all going.

Comment: And as far as SE is concerned I am strongly against editing posts and removing "offensive" terminology. We already have nice example where such things ca lead [Nancy's back, so I'm leaving and taking my money with me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390444/4267244) Hint, look at edit history.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Note that my answer doesn't suggest to forcefully edit posts. And note: when you have bully prominent developers (or HR folks) who are just searching for reasons to bully/fire people ... they will do that anyway. If they have a hidden agenda, then no matter what they do, it will serve that hidden agenda. Then the problem isnt that you change terminology, but that you have bullies in your organisation. Not changing terminology ... will not help with that problem.

Comment: "Bullies will bully", agreed. But, I don't want to give them additional ammo.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile On the other hand, the story you just told opened your eyes. You now have a more clear picture of that previously hidden agenda. These are smart people, they will find ammunition without your help. But now they exposed themselves. You now know about these people. You also know now that your org tolerates such open bullying. Tells you a lot about your workplace. Helps you making YOUR choices in such a setup.

Comment: This reads like an essay, not like it actually answers the question.

Comment: It gives a suggestion how SE Inc. *could* go about this, and it suggests a perspective how "affected" people can look at the topic.

Comment: Luckily, I don't work in any organization. So, I feel I have more freedom to speak out and oppose changing terminology "just because it might offend someone".

Comment: Not everybody using the communities on this network is in that position. And note again: there is a wide spectrum to deal with this. I get that "let's fight it" is your preferred approach, but it isn't one that works for everybody.

Comment: Right now I am strictly speaking about taking a stand here on SE. I am fully aware that people might not have choice in workplace or whatever other circumstances. I am not even saying that everyone must "join the fight" or do that openly. I am also not saying that we should never  ever change any terminology. But I am strictly against any kind of policing, editing or even suggesting that some terms might be offensive. SE should be neutral in all this. Anything else will not end well.

Comment: This is not if you are not with me, then you are against me kind of situation and I know many people will have different opinions. That is fine. My greatest fear (because I have seen some hints of that happening elsewhere) is turning terminology into a holy war, ostracizing anyone that objects to changes and/or posts questions or answers using "forbidden" terms.

Comment: What is your point? Do You say the lesson from that mess is to ignore any such discussion until it is driven down from SE INC? I prefer to have a question like this here, and answers looking at the different points of view so they become explicit. Instead of operating on implicit assumptions?

Comment: @RichardsaysReinstateMonica That is all a question of your mindset. In a truly agile setup, change is everywhere, all the time. If your mindset is to reject that, and instead you want "keep things as they are and I am used to" ... then you will constantly run into walls. "Embrace change" is about the idea of reminding yourself to question which position you WANT to start from.

Comment: Change is the only constant. But there is a world of difference between meaningful changes and useless changes. Additional problem in this particular type of change, is that it is political change, not functional, and because it is political, especially because it revolves around sensitive topic, it denies any discussion and criticism. It is not about whether your boss will tell you "we will use xxx terminology from now on" and you using that because that is how it is decided, but that asking "why?" can get you in trouble.

Comment: Also people that were in discussing and are in charge of change might have been in similar position where they could not speak freely.

Comment: @RichardsaysReinstateMonica Opinion, not fact. You are depicting your stance towards that "slogan" as if it were a fact. Yet, this is only your interpretation. I am simply pointing out that there other ways to look at this. This doesn't mean that my view is the better. But the same can be said for your take.

Comment: Again, opinion not fact. Our org preaches "embrace change", at the same time, anything that is under "local" control can be put on the table and be discussed to fix any such issues as "change going into the wrong direction". The slogan (and terms) isn't a problem, because, as written before: what counts is the practical reality. If I can discuss 95% of all "change" coming to me with my manager, and we resolve things on our level, I really do not care about the 5% that are originating from some VP executive 10 miles above me.

Comment: @GhostCat about opinion: My take is that opinion is to be valued, but that saying "opinion!" does not make for a point to negate or disprove others'. tldr: Such would be yours.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile "Bullies will bully": That is a fact. +1. But I'll *strongly* beg to add that it doesn't make for an excuse. That would be like saying "boys will be boys" as to excuse inappropriate behavior as a suggested part of normal.

Comment: I hope that it is very clear that I absolutely do not support or even excuse such behavior. I only want to point out that the real problem is with people who engage in such ways. The content they use for bullying is of 2nd nature, as it is never about the factual level.

Comment: And the opinion point is simply to remind people that their view isn't a neutral fact. But plenty of the people came over as "what I said is the truth, and there are only irrational reasons to disagree with me". That is what I object: to believe that some personal opinion is the same as objective truth. Also note I do not support language policing. But I also believe that fundamental change to the better requires to be open to question paradigms we are simply used to.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the thing to keep in mind is that language drives behavior. Even contrary behavior. "Don't eat the brownie" is going to encourage you if you're contrarian to eat the brownie. That drove behavior, and it wasn't even a lexicon change. You can easily change the way people think about things by using language, see: Fox News vs CNN. The New York Times vs Washington Post. Authors use words all the time to drive emotion and response. To suggest that we can't do the same "because it's software" is ridiculous on the face of things, and falls apart when poked at. It's uncomfortable, sure.

Comment: @jcolebrand Yes, the change of terms can and probably will affect how we think, but I expect the positive change to be very tiny, if noticeable at all, especially in comparison to the negative overhead of the change. Additionally, the roots of "black/dark = bad" themes in the language are not in the races; consider e.g. "black magic vs white magic". I assume it goes back to the old times, when darkness was dangerous as it could hide something that could eat you. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] *"Don't eat the brownie"* I'd argue that this is more about a response to a *command*, rather than a language. A command doesn't have to involve language; it could've been conveyed non-verbally with the same effect, e.g. gestured. *"Fox News vs CNN"* I'm not an American, not even a native speaker, so this example doesn't tell me much.

Comment: "And in case you consider such efforts to be completely ridiculous, I suggest you spend a few minutes watching "Malcom X" learn about the usage of the words black and white (see here)." Thank you. I am exactly as convinced as ever that such efforts are completely ridiculous, but I now have one more reference link I can use to make the argument that proponents of these changes are being intellectually dishonest. I'm also not a fan of the subtle implication that white people are not just inherently racist (itself a racist idea), but made so by Christianity (I am white and atheist).

Comment: "My company has put up an internal search engine. They suggest to use blocklist and to not use blacklist when writing new code/specs." Cool. See you in twenty years, when racists with a technical background are talking about "the problem with block people" as coded language. The euphemism treadmill doesn't fix anything, and never has, and cannot possibly ever; and everybody who has ever paid attention knows it. The problem with slurs isn't the phonemes, it's the idea.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem with people not being aware is: people not being aware. Pushing people to not re-consider their inherent beliefs is just that, raising awareness. If nothing changes, then nothing changes.

Comment: @GhostCat to say that there is a problem inherent in people "not being aware" of something, is to assert that it exists. The problem for your argument is that **it does not**. There is no evidence that, statistically, people who use terminology like "blacklist" and "master branch" harbour any racist "inherent beliefs" at above base rate, which is the only problem that could even theoretically be addressed this way. Certainly, the use of the terms themselves does not express such beliefs, and is never intended to do so. People who complain about these terms are making up reasons to be offended.

Comment: ... I hope someone will let me know if and when the activists responsible for changes like this achieve a consensus on a replacement for the obviously problematic term "audio remastering". I mean it's not even some weird false etymology like "history" containing "his"; the term really is formed from "master" by standard morphological rules. Clearly that's just as offensive as Git repositories having a master branch, right? (Irony mode off: I.e., **not** offensive.)