# What's a disallowed tag called now?

Tags: support, tags, terminology

Clearly there's a lot of work to do to fix it historically (and I will be quite miffed at people getting overenthusiastic about this) - but previously we had tag *blacklists* and tag blacklist requests.

We may have a need to request these, and considering it is a request for the use of an SE internal use, it might be a good opportunity to clarify and use the appropriate term for *new* requests.

Do we have tag *blocklists* or *denylists* now?

Comment: The [canonical post and FAQ proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag) uses the term "blocked tag", which (if I recall correctly) I edited *after* SE changed the name of the [tag:blacklist-request] tag to [tag:tag-block-request].

Comment: I remember now. The term I had come up with to edit was "banned tags", but I changed it to "blocked tags" instead because that's the term SE chose to rename the tags to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the related tags have been renamed to [blocked-tags](/questions/tagged/blocked-tags) and family.

Requests to block a tag can be done through the use of the [tag-block-request](/questions/tagged/tag-block-request) tag, and the [FAQ on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag) has been renamed to use the "block" terminology.

I ventured over to Meta Stack Overflow, and the related tags appear to be [blocklist-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocklist-request) and [tag-blocklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-blocklist). So I suppose the naming scheme varies per site.

As you mentioned, a rather large amount of work would be required to clean up all mentions of *tag blacklist* and family, but the blacklist tags have been [synonymized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) with the "block" terminology tags by an SE employee, with the exception of one last remaining [blacklist](/questions/tagged/blacklist) tag. So, at least that part is (mostly) taken care of.

The timing of those synonymizations (is that a word?) appears to line up with Yaakov Ellis's [post on SE's stance on the terminology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352702/622284), which mentions...

> In that vein, we would like to announce that we have made the following changes on all user-facing portions of the sites:
>
> - We can confirm that no instances of master/slave are shown in the UI
> - All instances of “blacklist” have been converted to “blocklist”
> - All instances of “whitelist” have been converted to “allowlist”

So... blocklist it is! It appears that this ("blocked tags" and "tag blocklist") is the official term to be used moving forward.

Comment: Not quite. The tag renaming of [tag:blacklist-request] -> [tag:tag-block-request] was done *by an SE employee*, which means that's the official term.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Yes, I had noticed that. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in my answer...

Comment: What I meant was, it means "blocked tags" is the official term.

Comment: Note: At some point, it looks like the [blacklist] tag was renamed to [blocklist] as well. (I don't know when it was renamed or by whom.)