# For moderators, please add the "undelete" button to all deleted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, comment-flags

Well, we're not *exactly* on the same page as a team on undeletions.

In dealing with the comments on this post — I noticed that a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations/391864#comment1310666_391847) (with broader context) containing *some* trigger keyword was automatically deleted. (Yes, I know regular users can't see it.)
In the interests of historical context, I wanted to undelete this comment *but* anything that a single flag deletes *can't* be undeleted inline — the undelete 'button' doesn't appear. In order to undelete it, I would have had to go to the user's complete list of comments, find it, and undelete it from there. That's a lot more work.

In this case it wouldn't make sense *outside* where it was, and who said it in the comment thread, so it wouldn't make sense to be reposted.

In the interests, of well, letting us curate comments, it would be nice to allow mods to undelete single flag comments. I've also noticed that self deleted comments can't be undeleted, I feel less strongly of these but I'd consider those too.

---

I was told it's technically possible, and found a way to do it, but it's obscure and hard to find. I've edited the scope of my post to reflect that.

Comment: Technically speaking, any comment can be undeleted - for comments deleted by someone other than a current moderator, you [can go to the user's list of comments and undelete from there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work "Any comment can be undeleted when the moderator is viewing the pages which list all comments created by a user, regardless of who deleted the comment.").

Comment: What is the blacklisted term in that comment?

Comment: "Accepted answer" I suspect

Comment: From the revisions of the post, I can see that there is a confusion between the terms `blocklisted` and `blacklisted`. Please, what is the significance of this difference?

Comment: Well, I also included a link in the edit comments saying why - it is what [SE uses internally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l/352702#352702), and as much as possible I'm trying to stick to that when talking about SE policies and such. It is *correct* in this context.

Comment: There's a more fundamental question: should anything be autodeleted, ever, without human intervention or action? Why not just cast an autoflag on things? Overall, my experience with automatic deletions or filters (not just on SE) is that blocking creation/posting tends to have a higher false positive rate than I'd like.

Comment: @ThomasOwens cause people abuse comments for things like "I CAN HAZ ACCEPTED ANSWER PLZ KTHZ" - or there's a few swearwords that trigger it off

Comment: @Glorfindel From what I understand, there is already a userscript to do this.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 This terminology change was [discussed a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l/352702#352702) and  we did review the public-facing UI to remove the problematic terms (though tag usage on sites may still include it). If there are places it was missed, we'd like to address that as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel As Catija said, there already is a userscript that shows the "undelete" button on all deleted comments for moderators: [Comment Undeleter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentUndeleter.user.js) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/CommentUndeleter.user.js)).

Comment: @Makyen The default UI on question pages makes it seem like undeleting comments that were self-deleted or deleted by Community (e.g. through flags) isn't possible. I think that most mods would be justified in framing a request in the way this is. I actually run into this occasionally and forget that I don't need a script to undelete such comments. Requesting a better UX for mods in context seems like a fair ask?

Comment: @Catija I have absolutely no problem with a bug or feature request that requests the "undelete" button to be shown for all comments. I'm not sure why it's not already that way. However, a request that is "please let us undelete all comments" is *inherently* [tag:status-completed], because the ability to do that already exists. That's why I was asking for the question to be [edit]ed such that it asks for the capability to be added to the UI, so it's more convenient use/do, rather than to ask for the capability to exist, which is what was initially asked for.

Comment: @Makyen As Catija said, a moderator could legitimately be unaware of the fact that comments can be undeleted from a user's comment list even if they can't be on the post itself. Also, the original announcement of the feature to undelete comments [states that it is restricted to cases where they were deleted by moderators](/a/170489/377214) (see the parenthetical note "in certain cases" and Shog9's reply comment there). Someone going off when the undelete button is shown on posts and said official announcement would not be aware that the restrictions don't apply from user comment lists.

Comment: @Makyen Also, as the announcement states, the restrictions against undeleting comments not deleted by moderators is part of the system's design. Being able to undelete any comment from the user's comment list technically violates that design and may have been an oversight when the team implemented comment lists. This is thus a request to change the design to allow for more comments to be undeleted, rather than a bug (and why I retagged it as such). This does mean that the original phrasing of this question makes sense when you only consider the intended system design and not deviations from it

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No, it doesn't. Asking "let us do X, because it's not possible to do X" is *inherently* [tag:status-completed] when you are able to do X. Given that moderators can already do X, the *original version* of this question was, actually, [tag:status-completed] when it was written. For that, it doesn't matter if moderators weren't aware or what was intended back in 2013, or if anyone at the company still feels that's a good idea, or not. The designers *clearly* later chose to allow it. But all that *doesn't matter* for what was in the *original version* of this question.

Comment: The *original version* was *only* asking for something to exist that already existed. What I asked for was for the question to be edited to *reflect reality* and to actually say what the real intent was as to what was being asked for. You're bringing a *boatload* of stuff into this, which *just didn't exist in the original version*. The *original version* strictly asked for the existence of X when X already existed. Sure, the question could be edited to be something else, which is what my original comment asked for.

Comment: Hold on, comments that say (rot13 just in case!) `npprcgrq nafjre` are eligible for automatic deletion? That seems like it would make it difficult to discuss, or even *explain*, duplicate closures properly.

Comment: Yes, I do suspect the words accepted answer are going to get your post one flag deleted, and if you're fast enough, you can try it on this post before someone else does :D.

Comment: There's also a length limit. For some specific trigger words, if the comment is longer than a certain length, it will not be deleted instantly after a single flag.