# Why isn't there a "Jon Skeet" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, fun

It's 2017 and we don't have a Jon Skeet tag on SO and SE?!

Comment: Feature requests must explain a problem that needs solving. Why do we need this, what benefit does it provide, what is the purpose of the tag?

Comment: Jon Skeet is just a **normal guy** on the Stack Exchange network with a lot of reps. He doesn't need a tag.

Comment: No. Actually, it has been created quite often and then it gets deleted by regulars (read: the regulars remove it from all questions and then it gets deleted by the system as an unused tag).

Comment: Case in point: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/320188/revisions  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/71642/revisions

Comment: @Glorfindel then it should be hard-coded in the SO and SE ;)

Comment: it sounds like it should be blacklisted

Comment: I interpreted the request to add the tag as being whimsical (i.e. a joke), but I see that everyone has taken it quite seriously. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than there not ever being a [jon-skeet](/questions/tagged/jon-skeet) tag, it seems from the [comment by @Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304040/why-isnt-there-a-jon-skeet-tag/304043#comment988388_304040) that:

> it has been created quite often and then it gets deleted by regulars
>   (read: the regulars remove it from all questions and then it gets
>   deleted by the system as an unused tag).

This indicates that the reason there is not a [jon-skeet](/questions/tagged/jon-skeet) tag is that the community sees no case for its existence and burninates it whenever it is re-created.

Rather than creating it or repeated burnination it seems to me like [blacklisting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/215590) it may be more appropriate.

Comment: Jon Skeet is an icon of SO, and there are many questions/answers targeting himself specifically, "his approach", "his opinion", "his life style", "his questions", "his answers", "his comments", etc. To me (and many others), reading and searching for these has been making me a better programmer. So why not have a tag for such questions!?

Comment: You don't need a tag to search for him, you can search for a user, so that would be redundant. @evilreiko

Comment: @evilReiko Jon Skeet"s iconicity is partly memetic. That is to say, his fame is deserved -- he knows his stuff and explains things very well -- but the meme status is partly because he has meme status, so people talk about his fame, and it becomes a self-reinforcing feedback loop.