# How can I suggest a tag synonym when the system doesn’t recognise a tag?

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, tag-synonyms

At [LawSE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) there is the [united-kingdouk](/questions/tagged/united-kingdouk) tag which has a typo and is frequently used by at least one user necessitating others to edit posts and replace it with [united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom).

To negate the need for these edits  I attempted to make the former a synonym of the latter, but go the error message:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!

But it does exist on the system - albeit with conflicting information, i.e. zero questions -v- one asked this year:

[image: tag description]

Notwithstanding this contradictory information, is the lack of questions the reason for my failure to synonymise?

If so, what are the options to get rid of [united-kingdouk](/questions/tagged/united-kingdouk), bearing in mind it keeps being used so probably won't get deleted due to lack of use?

**Update**

I' ve dip sampled the [united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) questions and found half a dozen examples of [united-kingdouk](/questions/tagged/united-kingdouk) being used and then edited out which doesn't tally with the comments that it should be removed with 24 hours - unless I'm missing something..?

[#1](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/85303/35069)

[#2](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/84841/35069)

[#3](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81543/35069)

[#4](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/80540/35069)

[#5](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/80056/35069)

[#6](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/79655/35069)

I went back as far as April 2022 as I was doing it manually on a phone - if someone knows of a SEDE enquiry that can search edit histories then there may be more to find.

Comment: That's not what I see at this moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU6gp.png - I think the tag should be deleted by tomorrow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/295232

Comment: As you can check in the [revision history](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/85358/revisions), the tag was created in this question: [What is an example of indirect discrimination?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/85358) As already mentioned, it should be removed in 24 hours (unless it is used on another question). You can find more information in the [tag-info for tag-pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info).

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, that user has enough reputation to create a new tag, thus the [united-kingdouk] tag will be created again if that user manually types it. You might want to request on Meta Law to [add this tag to the tag blocklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/241919) if this tag is unwarranted. Otherwise, ask a mod to create a tag synonym, they can bypass the restriction for creating a tag synonym with non-existent tags.

Comment: @Glorfindel It seems that this rouge tag was autocorrected when the user manually typed it. It has now been dealt with. I don't know the etiquette for these situations, but would it be too much trouble for you to mark this post as [status-norepo], please? Thanks.