# Preventing the use of "spaces in tags"

Tags: discussion, tags

On StackOverflow, I often see questions by newbies tagged with separate words that should have been a single tag. For example, just now I edited `google` `app` `engine` `python` to read `google-app-engine` `python`. An understandable mistake for someone who doesn't yet know how the tags work.

Generally, users with editing powers will quickly fix this. But maybe we can come up with a way to prevent the problem altogether?

Answer (score 3):

I think this means we should really be considering redesigning the tagging interface. Not to add more work to Jeff and co. but if the tag interface is a single text box with  only cursory hints as to how it's used, it's no wonder people keep putting spaces inappropriately.

Perhaps five text boxes, one for each tag (since there already *is* a limit on how many tags) would make the situation clearer. Then we can unambiguously convert spaces to dashes and make adjustments, knowing clearly (or clearer) what a confused newbie meant.

That may not be the cleanest or most friendly solution, but it is just an idea. I'm just presenting it as an alternative to the current interface, which seems to cause confusion.

Comment: "That may not be the cleanest or most friendly solution" that is putting it.. *mildly*

Comment: You'll end up with the opposite problem of people putting all the tags in one box and ending up with them all in a big mess.

Comment: You could put a note above them saying, possibly, "Tags (1 per box)" Anyway, my point is that if this is such a persistent problem, the interface is at fault.

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to ...

- [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)
- [Implement a Tag Black List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

... although [google] and [python] are reasonable tags, [app] and [engine] should probably be blacklisted (in a more gentle way?) as too general to be useful?

Comment: See following tweet: http://twitter.com/chacha102/status/13774907303

Answer (score 1):

In the popup tag selection box, the top entries should be known tags that have the previous tags joined by dashes. This won't prevent the problem completely, but it *could* make the asker stop and think "oh, maybe that's what I really want".