# how to keep a tag wiki for an empty tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Empty tags are deleted after 24 hours, if I understand correctly.

Right now, on Mi Yodeya, we have a tag which has been used in the past which we do not want used.  It currently has a warning as the [tag wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/torah/info).

The tag right now has only one question, which was migrated and will be auto-deleted after enough time goes by. At that point, the tag will be deleted, and with it the warning will go.

Aside from randomly assigning a question to host that tag, is there a way to keep the warning?  Is there an alternative suggestion of how to prevent users from using an unproductive tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the tag really makes absolutely no sense, and nobody should ever attempt to use it, you can request that it be [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/189912). You can also do this on your own site's meta; the devs will see it in 6 to 8 weeks...