# Mark a tag as a historical significance only

Tags: feature-request, tags, historical-lock

[We already have tag blacklisting.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) That's great, and very useful. **I would also like to have a related feature: marking a tag as "historical only".**

For example, on Programmers.SE, one of the custom close-reasons is for questions that are about [career or education advice, salary, or compensation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions seeking career or education advice are off topic on Programmers. They are only meaningful to the asker and do not generate lasting value for the broader programming community. Furthermore, in most cases, any answer is going to be a subjective opinion that may not take into account all the nuances of a (your) particular circumstance.

So... why even have a tag for [**career-development**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/career-development/info)? Because we have questions like these that should keep the tag:

- [I'm graduating with a Computer Science degree but I don't feel like I know how to program](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43528/im-graduating-with-a-computer-science-degree-but-i-dont-feel-like-i-know-how-t)
- [I don't program in my spare time. Does that make me a bad developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48698/i-dont-program-in-my-spare-time-does-that-make-me-a-bad-developer)
- [Is 4-5 years the “Midlife Crisis” for a programming career?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30449/is-4-5-years-the-midlife-crisis-for-a-programming-career)

All of these are closed with "historical significance". I think we should keep these questions, tagged as they are, but disallow any new posts from using this tag. So it's not *quite* a blacklist.

Comment: This is actually how the tag blacklist already works. It only prevents new questions from getting the tag. It doesn't automatically burn it from all the existing questions. But from the tag wiki you linked: *"Questions about developing one's career can be asked as long as they invite the unique insights of a programmer and are specifically about developing one's career as a programmer."* It doesn't appear the tag is *completely* off-topic, just mostly.

Comment: The main example you use of the career-development tag kind of falls short here in my opinion because that tag is not even blacklisted with the all caps don't use this tag warning. It looks like a regular tag to me. It even has some open questions in it (although a majority do seem to be closed or duplicates). Why not ask this on programmer's meta and burninate it or deal with the tag in that manner. The examples used here, in my opinion, seem like they should be dealt with in the context of Programmers, and not used as a generic template for the entire exchange.

Comment: That tag wiki needs to be updated. Some of the other career/education tag wikis indicate they should not be used, but people still use them anyway.

Comment: @animuson I did not realize that. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson Are you sure? In the past, we've been told that blacklisting a tag requires there to be no questions with that tag. I think that was about 2 years ago, though.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes, we've done this exact thing with the [code-golf tag  over on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759).