# Is "belongs-on-serverfault" a real tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I mean, really.  I like ice cream, but you don't see me making an i-like-ice-cream tag on SO.

If it really belongs on ServerFault, can't I be trusted to figure that out on my own?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag

Comment: Maybe this would be a good time to implement the tags blacklist. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We generally frown on the use of the "belongs-on-" tags.  Tags are supposed to be used to categorize questions, not direct what site a question belongs on.  People can flag for a moderator if they don't have the reputation to vote to close.  It also looks stupid once a question is migrated to retain the tag, just making more work on both ends (adding the tag and removing it later).

Answer (score 1):

It is a generally frowned upon tactic, but I can see why some people who may not have the ability to vote may retag it in such a way to alert higher rep users who may be skimming the question lists.

I would also say that "bogus-tags" is not a very good tag itself. It has not been used any other times (at least not when this was written according to the sidebar). The purpose of tagging in general is to categorize questions into the correct buckets, and there are much larger and more comprehensive tags about tagging.

Comment: The bogus-tags tag was a self-referential joke (and apparently not a funny one at that).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the reasons TheTXI listed, it also let's new users know where they should have posted it.

Comment: If they even know what a tag is.

Comment: For new users, I feel a "welcome to SO" type comment with an explanation of what's about to happen to their question is appropriate.

Comment: Example welcome comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426373/what-system-resoucrce-the-computer-use-to-open-a-cmd-window

Comment: The "this question has been migrated" link lets new users know where they should have posted.

Comment: @Bill, yes once it's been migrated.