# Questions with tag "Not Programming Related" is closed by marking it as "Not Programming Related" !

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we disallow the use of “belongs-on-xxxxxxx” and “not-programming-related” tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag)

As the title says, i have seen few questions where the owner of the question had tagged it as "Not Programming Related" and still it's closed by marking it as "Not Programming Related"

So, I am really confused how to handle with "Not Programming Related" tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just think of a tag like **[not-programming-related]** like an abuse of the tag system in the same way that [**[belongs-on-]**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/is-belongs-on-serverfault-a-real-tag) is.

Generally injected into your eyeballs by those who, although they have enough rep to flag and/or comment what they think the question should be closed for, will instead retag with this nonsense.

If you see it, [remove it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag).

Comment: @random, that link clears up a lot of misconceptions. Everyone should read it.

Comment: Which link are you talking about?

Comment: Ok, the *last* one.

Answer (score 1):

So? Do you also think that questions tagged `offensive` shouldn't be closed as offensive?

Comment: Yes. If it is offensive, flag it as offensive so it gets closed. Everything else just clutters the site.

Comment: i think, existence of "offensive" tag itself offensive