# "belongs-on" tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we disallow the use of “belongs-on-xxxxxxx” and “not-programming-related” tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag)

Is there an official position on this? Do we or don't we like adding "belongs-on-x" tags when closing? Personally I don't like it at all, since it's editing the question itself to support the closer's opinion, which hasn't been validated by the community yet.

Comment: I'd say this is a (near) duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag

Comment: @Stephan202 thanks, I figured it'd been discussed but couldn't find any definitive answer.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with you.  I don't see what purpose the tags serve.  Is anyone going to search for posts based on a "belongs-on-x" tag?  I don't see why they would.  They just cause a little more work when a post does get migrated and the now silly looking tag needs to be removed.  I remove them when I see them.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the official position from Jeff is that belongs-on-* should not even exist:

> [you're not going deep enough: these tags should not exist, period.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/change-the-belongs-on-serverfault-tag-when-a-question-is-moved-to-serverfault/4211#4211)

I swear I thought there was also another answer of Jeff's on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/belongs-on-tags/22099#22099) ... But I do not see it anymore.

That's about as close to official policy as we can get. I started retagging a bunch of `[belongs-on-superuser]`-tagged items last week when I started seeing it a lot on SO. (Mostly guys who just got the ability to retag.)

Answer (score 1):

Since I believe a feature is in the works to prevent users tagging things as `belongs-on-x` ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)), I think they should not be used. Also, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag) details how to deal with occurrences of them.