# Add option to flag posts for migration

Tags: feature-request, migration, flags

Would an option of flagging questions as needing Migration in addition to the the *Offensive* and *Spam* categories help the moderators in triaging flagged questions more efficiently?

All of the posts I have flagged have been migrations and the only sensible option left is *Requires Moderator Attention*. I'm not sure how much other use of the *Requires Moderator Attention* there is apart from flagging questions for migration. You could still enter information on why the question has been flagged much as you do now with the *Requires Moderator Attention*.

Update: I asked this question because I don't have enough rep to vote to close questions but still want to participate with flagging questions. I thought that having another category might help the moderators with the number of questions they need to deal with.

Answer (score 8):

As it stands today questions are voted to close as belonging on a different site.  While moderator votes are binding (they happen right away), moving from voting to flagging would make the decision to close/migrate one that is solely the responsibility of the moderators.  I prefer that we continue the practice of (generally) letting the community decide the appropriate forum.

If you aren't intending that the process of migration be changed, i.e., still allow votes for closing, then I don't see how adding a different flag reason really helps as the "requires moderator attention" already allows you to specify a reason.  This more general mechanism seems better suited to the wide range of things a moderator might need to look at than adding to the number of available options.

Comment: Some of us who ain't got the rep to vote would like to be helpful in noticing migration candidates. And some of us only recently learned that taggings isn't the way to do that. An extra checkbox might make that more transparent.

Comment: I think migration, because it's non-destructive, ought to be separate from closing and have a lower rep requirement.  I don't think we should necessarily make it easier to go around the privilege system that has already been set up to basically grant privileges (through moderators) to people who haven't earned them.

Comment: @tvanfosson I am not suggesting that the privilege system should be undermined. As you point out the system already provides the ability for people to flag questions for moderator attention, all I'm proposing is that an extra option be added for migration to help them sort through the questions more efficiently and to reduce the confusion of users who haven't earned enough reputation to vote to close but want to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 4):

Tagging for migration is [improper use of the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/belongs-on-just-does-not-belong) and is discouraged.

Flagging for moderator attention, with a short reason as to why it's better suited on another site is already there, so use it.

Requires Moderator attention can also be used for:

- Flagging a user for suspicious or hateful behaviour
- Asking for a rep recalc
- Pointing out questions that are exact dupes and could be merged (Especially when it's the same user who only waited 11 minutes before reposting the exact same thing)

Comment: I didn't mean to use tagging when I meant flagging - I have edited my question to clarify that.