# Is it possible to retag migrated questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, tags

In the moderation tools on Stack Overflow, I found [a question introducing a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959661/why-changes-that-i-made-in-csv-file-dont-save-closed): **[excell]**.
Obviously a typo.

But I can't retag it because it was migrated to Super User and apparently deleted there.

Is there a way to retag migrated questions by non-admins? if not, would someone please fix this?

Comment: I fixed the typo in the tag.  Thanks for bringing it to our attention.  I also wasn't aware that people couldn't flag on migrated posts, which seems at least mildly annoying.  I guess we're supposed to flag on the destination site instead?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah flagging on the destination seems reasonable.

Comment: @Bill: Could you remove [google-dart] too? [dart] is used instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-dart

Comment: @Jonas: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, no. There is no way for non-moderators to retag/edit a migrated question on the departure site.

Migrated questions are essentially locked on the site they started on.

This means you can't even flag for moderator attention about any tagged typos or [frowned upon tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/belongs-on-tag-does-not-belong).

Comment: +1 - this is a bug-bear of mine too.