# Keep moderator flag link on migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, flags, moderators

I was cleaning up tags, came to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553862/changing-time-zone-on-linux-by-using-command-closed) and since it was migrated I couldn't edit the tags.  I wanted to flag for the moderator, but found that migrated posts don't have flag links.  I think we should keep the flag link on the migrated posts for situations like this (and also in case it got migrated but was offensive, and people still wanted to flag it).

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/ability-to-flag-locked-posts, I believe.

Comment: @mmyers, I'm not sure if the reason you can't flag the migrated post is because it's locked, but it certainly could be.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/is-it-possible-to-retag-migrated-questions

Comment: @John, yes, that would be a dupe of the problem, so now this is the feature-request to get that changed.  Please keep this open.

Comment: @Lance: You misunderstood. The dupe is mmyers' link. My link only shows that his link is the dupe.

Comment: @John, ok, got it

Comment: You can fake it out by adding `?noredirect=1` to the URL of the original.

Answer (score 2):

Migrated posts now display the option to flag for moderator attention.

[image: Flagging migrated posts]

Comment: I'm aware this is an an old question, but it never received a proper answer, so I thought I'd clarify the issue had been fixed.

Comment: It was marked status-completed. That's the signal on meta that it's fixed. Unless there's something else to say it doesn't really need an answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I assumed that Stack Exchange users coming from other non-meta sites may not always check the question tags and may go looking for an accepted answer instead

Comment: Other stack exchange users won't be looking for this issue as it was fixed 7 years ago.